# How to remove dotted border around active hyperlinks in IE8 with CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Active hyperlink texts are highlighted with dotted border. When using effects on such hyperlinks (fadeIn/fadeOut) it produces strange effects. How do I disable/remove the dotted border?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
a:active, a:selected, a:visited { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Note that this has to be after any `a:hover` rules. Thanks to [PEra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421508/pera) in the comments for suggesting using the `a:selected` selector as well.

**NOTE**

The above does *not* work in IE 9.  Removing a:selected causes it to work in IE9.

Comment: For me, this works in IE8, but FF3.5 ignores it. It still shows dotted border when link is active. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore, I found that FF ignores this css :(

Comment: I'm really not sure; perhaps the other answers on this question would be of more help to you.

Comment: I had to set these for a:visited, too.

Comment: a:selected appears to not work in IE9.  Removing that selector from the snippet above did the trick for me.

Comment: In Firefox you can do this: 

:-moz-any-link:focus {
 outline: none;
}

Comment: `a:selected` didn't work in IE8 for me - replaced it with `a:focus`

Comment: @Zack I also had to remove `a:selected` to work on Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: [Don't do this though](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/do_not_remove_the_outline_from_links_and_form_controls/)

Answer (score 33):

Typical and safe way to do it is this:

```
a:active, a:focus {
   outline:  none; /* non-IE */
   ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true); /* IE6-7 */
}
```

Since `expresssion()` has been gutted in IE8, you may need a script:

```
if (document.documentElement.attachEvent)
    document.documentElement.attachEvent('onmousedown',function(){
         event.srcElement.hideFocus=true
    });
```

If you're going to remove the default focus outline, **you must  define your own distinct style for `:focus`**, otherwise keyboard users will have a hard time using your site.

Answer (score 15):

Be careful. The dotted-border is a valuable part of keyboard-browsing. It highlights which link will be clicked.

```
a:active { outline: none; }
```

Author Nathan Smith gives [a more thorough discussion of this](http://sonspring.com/journal/removing-dotted-links), and various related issues on his blog.

Comment: Might want to say keyboard browsing rather than tabbed browsing.

Comment: Yes, it is must for accessibility, for the people with disabilities.

Answer (score 12):

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to be a little more explicit in yours answers. It is perftly correct, but lake of a bit of information. Also you can use the format function for code. and again, welcome to SO !

Answer (score 10):

Try with this CSS:

For **Mozilla**:

```
|:-moz-any-link:focus { outline: none; }

|:focus { outline: none; }

button, input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { outline: none; }

button::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner, input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner { padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px; border: 1px dotted transparent; }
```

---

For **IE8**:

```
a:active, a:focus { 
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The a `{ outline: none; }` breaks keyboard usability. And the `a:active {}` selector seems to break it just as good last time I checked in Firefox.

There is a JS way to get rid of the border without breaking anything, as well as JS code to get rid of the border in IE6 and IE7.

I described the method in [my tutorial](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/view?tut=Removing-Dotted-Border-on-Clicked-Links).

Comment: @Barney, sure enough, he didn't do that and now his code is gone lol

Answer (score 3):

Solution in JavaScript to remove the active border on the links on all the browsers:
add the event **onfocus="this.blur();"** on your link

```
<a href="#" onfocus="this.blur()"> Link </a>
```

NOTE: this will work in all browsers.

Comment: css was not working for me in cordova app, and it worked

Comment: This is the only method I found that worked for buttons in IE9. I was going to give up already. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
a:focus, *:focus {
    noFocusLine: expression(this.onFocus=this.blur());
}
```

Taken from here:
http://www.cssjunction.com/css/remove-dotted-border-in-ie7/

Answer (score 2):

This one works the best for me

```
a{
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i wanted to get this working for Button and this worked for me

```
button { 

    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;    
    background-color: transparent;
    noFocusLine: expression(this.onFocus=this.blur());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use outline:0 on object and embed. some basic zeroing out css would look like this:

```
a, a:visited { 
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #e3a512; 
    }
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
    outline:0;
    }
object, embed, a, a img, a:active, a:selected, a:visited {
    outline:0
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

```
a img {border: none; }
```

that's it, no need to complicate this.