# gray striked outline box around img tag

Tags: html, css

I have several img tags inside of a hrefs that I use as buttons and for some reason in IE when I click the img it creates a gray box around the tag, however this only happens in IE.  Any ideas on how to remove it?

Here is the code.

```
<div style="padding-left:115px; text-decoration:none">
<a href="javascript:changecolor(1)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(2)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:600px"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(3)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:600px"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(4)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:600px"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(7)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:600px"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" style="margin-top:600px;" /></a>
<a href="javascript:changecolor(6)" title="Click Again to Change Color" style="cursor:pointer; margin-top:600px"><img src="button.png" width="25" height="25" /></a>
</div>
```

These are the img tags that get a gray striked outline around them when clicked.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142819/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-active-hyperlinks-in-ie8-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add This

```
a
 {
  outline: none;
 }
```