# Remove the AnchorTag IE Border

Tags: html, css

I have an UL with ListItems containing AnchorTags.

These Anchor Buttons should have Borders, depending on the click event.
However in IE and Firefox- when the Anchor is clicked it automatically puts this dashed-border surrounding the Button.  You have to click away from it in order for that Border to dissapear:

[image]

Here is a Fiddle and you can see what Im talking about:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/ZSeFA/

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: **sidebar knows all** possible duplicate of [CSS - remove border in input buttons when selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913335/css-remove-border-in-input-buttons-when-selected)

Comment: @Matt absolutely I tried to search for this- thanks for being snide.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142819/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-active-hyperlinks-in-ie8-with-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#mid-featureleft-client .navigations a:focus {  
    outline: none;  
}
```