# Removing Focus from a link, once clicked in CSS drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have a css drop down menu (below), however, my problem is this, once a drop menu option (link) is clicked, nasty ie. 7 leaves an unwated rectangular fine dotted line focus that appears long after a menu option is clicked. How can I remove the focus of the link after it has been clicked?

```
    <div id="menu" style="width: 1001px; height: 20px">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="file">File</div></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="window.print()"><div id="print">Print</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_update()"><div id="save">Save</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_update('s');window.close()"><div id="saveandexit">Save & Exit</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="window.close()"><div id="exit">Exit</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="edit">Edit</div></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_addnew();return false"><div id="addnew">Add new</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="delete">Delete</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_reset()"><div id="clear">Clear Form</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="view">View</div></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_first">&gt;&gt; Go to First</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_next">&gt;Go to Next</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_prev">Go to Previous&gt;</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="goto_last">Go to Last&gt;&gt;</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="reports">Reports</div></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="export_excel">Export to Excel Table</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="export_html">Export to HTML Table</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo" onclick="sims_compile_htmllist()"><div id="export_list">Export to HTML List</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#nogo"><div id="logoff">Logoff</div></a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
/*HORIZONTAL DROP-DOWN MENU */
#menuwrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;

    background-color: #A9BBD3;
    height: 19px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 100%;

}


#menu{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 31px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 1001px;
}
#menu ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menu li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
    display:inline;

} 

#menu li a{
    width:125px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #A9BBD3;
    color: #FFF;
} 

#menu li a:hover{
    background-color: #446087;
} 
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul ul li a {
    width: 120px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    text-align:center;
}
#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Try adding * { outline:none; } to your css.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `outline:none` in the css like,

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
}
```

Better, you need to add this bit of code in your `reset.css` if you have..

Clicking down on an input type=image can produce a dotted outline (Does this in Firefox 3.6.8 but not Firefox 4). To remove it:

```
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

Hope, it helps..

Answer (score 0):

The same question was already answered here:
[How to remove dotted border around active hyperlinks in IE8 with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142819/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-active-hyperlinks-in-ie8-with-css)

Look the note for IE.