# IE, CSS: How to remove a highlight which appears, when click the button

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, highlight

Take a look at this page in IE (I have the newest version, but it also happens in older versions.)

http://tinuska.vibraflex.cz/

In above link there are two round buttons at bottom of the page. When you click the button, a semi-transparent highlight around the button appears. It doesn't appear in Mozilla or Chrome. Is it possible to remove it somehow?

[image]

Comment: Don't see it? Tried in IE10 with and without compatibility mode.

Comment: Are you talking about the dotted outline?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142819/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-active-hyperlinks-in-ie8-with-css

Comment: it would be awesome if you had a jsFiddle for you *homework*

Comment: Can't you see this? I cropped this from a screenshot.
http://tinuska.vibraflex.cz/img/highlightProb.png

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra style in anchor tag.

```
style="background-color:transparent"
```

Comment: The background color fix wont work well if we have coloured button, as this would change their actual color. Try the focus outline:none css

Answer (score 1):

**TRY It.**
The below code of css is useful for remove the border and focus around the link or button.

```
a:focus{
 outline:none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Exact fix @RanaAalamgeer

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can add these style attributes to your anchor buttons btn1 and btn2:

```
border-top-left-radius: 41px;
border-top-right-radius: 41px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 41px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 41px;
```

I've tried with IE10 and it's working.

An example for btn1:

```
<a id="btn1" href="#" style="border-top-left-radius: 41px; border-top-right-radius: 41px; border-bottom-right-radius: 41px; border-bottom-left-radius: 41px;"/>
```