# How to remove href underline inside a div element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove an underline from an href, that is wrapped in a div element. But for some reason it is not being removed.

Can anyone please help me? Below is the code.

```
 <style>


     a .menu_items {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size: 34px;
        color:red;

    }

   </style>
    </head>
    <body>

                <a href="#"><div class="menu_items"> Pizza  </div></a>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207345/css-how-do-i-remove-the-underline-from-a-link-that-isnt-directly-in-the-anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this and it will be easier after developing more pages and you will not have to create a style for each one you only have to call your style from your css

i explain you...you have to found your css default in your project or create a new one and load in your page where you want to call the styles that you will create in your css file....insert this in your css

```
 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 34px;
    color:red;

}
```

and in your page after loading your css file you only have to copy this as you were codding

```
    <body>    
                <a href="#"><div class="menu_items"> Pizza  </div></a>
</body>
```

i hope i helped you

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Cause you are trying add `text-decoration` to the div with class `.menu_items` but not for tag `a`

Answer (score 0):

Please try putting the A link inside the DIV then reverse the CSS order. I believe the other way around is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

just delete the selector '.menu_items' like this

```
<style>
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size: 34px;
        color:red;
    }

</style>
<a href="#">
    <div class="menu_items"> 
        Pizza  
    </div>
</a>
```

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpMDc/)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property for removing the underline is

```
text-decoration:underline;
```

You will need to apply this to your anchor element.

See this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/CzDkH/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Place this above all your styles:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Get in the habit of placing all `a` , `html` , and `body` style properties at the top of your styles too! It will save you from headaches like this.

Happy styling :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do it for the class "menu_items" and not in the rest of the page, the only thing is you've got it back to front. It's like this:

```css
   .menu_items a {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size: 34px;
        color:red;

    }
```

Similarly you've got the div inside the a tag, and should have the a tag inside the div

```html
<div class="menu_items"><a href="#">Pizza</a></div>
```