# CSS a:hover is strangely inheriting styles

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, inheritance

I realize that if I'm styling a link in CSS, using a parent element with a class name, i.e.:

```
div.class a { ... }
```

The hover state of the link is also inheriting this stylesheet, but only if I prescribed a specific class.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8CqW/)

How to get around this with no duplicating of :hover stylesheets?

Comment: i wonder why it doesn't work when you don't even override again the `:hover` class. strange

Comment: it's not strange at all :) - it's called "selector specificity": http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `div.div a` is more specific than the selector `a:hover`, so it will take precedence.

If you make the hover selector more specific, it will be used for the last div also. For example:

```
html body a:hover {color:#d00;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's better solution opposed to !importnat

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!important` for your hover style.

```
a:hover {color:#d00 !important;}
```

Comment: I know it but it also not so good decision for me. 'Cause I need to make the styles of the links to be editable with CSS editor which I need to create further (like Firebug but its will be built in the admin panel). And it will be dificult to detect if there is a !importnan in the specific element or not

Comment: Well, you didn't mentioned this requirement in your question. You should then use Guffa's solution.

Comment: `!important` is a last resort and should only be used when appropriate. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-a-css-property