# Div's display: none gets overridden by user agent stylesheet, but works locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code on my website:

```
<div class="test_section no_display" id="test_section_metric">
      <div class="section_start_bar">

      </div>
      <div class="section_end_bar">

      </div>
</div>
```

And this piece of css:

```
.test_section
{
    width:70%;
    margin-left:15%;
    background-color: var(--color_main);
}

.no_display
{
    display: none;
}
```

But the div with "no_display" class is displayed, because when I inspect the site in Chrome I see that it overrides it with user agent stylesheet like this:

```
div{
    display:block;
}
```

However, when I open the site just as a file on my computer it is actually not displaying and is working as intended.

I've already searched for an answer, but I've mostly encountered people fixing it by putting a `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the `<html>` tag, which I've already done.

The .no_display class is a separate thing, because it'll be removed with javascript to show things on a button click.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is not in this code. Please post more of it. Also, check in your CSS if you have a style `#test_section_metric` for the `id` of the div.

Comment: Can we see the actual website, or do you have a plunkr showing this behaviour?

Comment: Try `display: none!important;`

Comment: Look at `Computed Style` tab, it is like a summary of all the styles that are affecting an element. It will probably have `display:none` since most styles on an agent sheet were meant to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

using css property **display: none !important;** will override the user agent setting. bonus points for checking that your class name and css class selector are spelled the same

Comment: Using the `!important` rule is generally considered to be **a really bad idea**. This is because it can cause problems down the road when it comes to "debugging" your CSS.
See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception)

Comment: @joeldesante Not in some cases. If OP cannot control the user agent setting, this kind of is a last resort. Read other devs discussion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8360190/6670491).

Answer (score 0):

For those who arrived here and have tried everything, and still failed, perhaps this tip can help you.

In my case, the **Ad Blocker** is the one who was adding **"user agent stylesheet"** `display: none;` in my div.

**Disabling it solved it!**