# My media query is not taking effect

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm having some trouble using a media query. It's quite a basic thing but for some reason is not working.

Basically, I have a border around a div tag:

```
<div class="container games mobile">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 div border"> 
<!-- This div tags are closed at the end of the file -->
```

I'm using bootstrap and don't honestly know if that can be part of the problem but what I wanted to do was to remove that border whenever the user was in a mobile, and to do so, I added the following lines in my css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       .border {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

[Border on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5cs1.png)

[Border on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr3cz.png) even though I used the querie

(added a grey square on both prints because the content doesn't really need to be in here but a live preview can be found [here](http://gamestorrent.kirtle.eu))

Could the issue be parent>child related?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because it's being overwritten by bootstrap code. Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
       .border {
        border: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was almost certain there wasn't a border class in bootstrap that's why I didn't even bother on checking *sigh. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes its better to avoid using !imporatant, when things can be handled using normal hierarchy.

Comment: No problem! I agree, avoid using `!important` as much as you can. For the sake of your issue we are going with a quick-fix, but ideally you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) here instead using `!important`. why not [!important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property)?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .games.mobile .border {
      border: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about css specificity. Gonna take a look at it and try to use it in the future! I could have fixed many of my problems already if I knew this before xD

Comment: that's why added the links, feel free to spend time on it.