# HTML/CSS. need help just making my border fill the entire width of the screen

Tags: html, css

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu0AF.jpg) https://melchillington.github.io/Website1/contact.html
That is my site so far, my issue is in the contact page but also a similar issue with the image on home page (index.html) any helpful tips/advice regarding anything will also be apprecaited I am new to html but wanted to code a website as practice starting from a free template I found online

```css
.headerC {
  background: #89cff0;
  font: 36pt/40pt courier;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0.1;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border: thick dashed hotpink;
  width: fill;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerC">
  <h1 align="center">Contact</h1>
  <h5 align="center"> <a href="tel:203-831-9722" class="link">203-831-9722</a></h5>
  <h5 align="center">234 East Ave 06855</h5>
  <h6 align="center">Norwalk, CT</h6>

</div>
```

Basically I just want that pink dotted border to fill the width I tried a few things but nothing seems to work

Comment: it's by default filling the width, what is the issue?

Comment: I want the width of the boarder to fill the screen but instead it is only a portion of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `max-width: 960px` set on all divs within the element with the id of '`body`'.

You need to override this styling on this particular element.
Either remove that max-width (note: This may have unintended consequences on other elements, without knowledge of your codebase I can't say if this is safe), or alternatively you could set `max-width: none !important;` on the `.headerC` element.

As an aside: the use of !important is generally frowned upon, and it's better to have a more organised and well formed CSS structure, but that's out of scope of this question, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property).

EDIT: For the image on index.html you'll need a slightly different approach. Remove the image element from the HTML:

```
<img src="images/truck.jpg" alt="">
```

and instead use the image as a background image on the `.header` element like so with CSS:

```
background-image: url('images/truck.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 10%;
```

So your CSS for the `.header` element will now look like:

```
#body.home div.header {
    background-image: url('images/truck.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 10%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use the background-position attribute to position the image as you desire.

You will also be able to remove the following from the CSS as it's now redundant:

```
#body.home div.header img {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 -563px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1126px;
}
```

Comment: thank you!! that worked like a charm :) I appreciate it

Comment: is there a way to make my image on index.html also fill width

Comment: @MelissaChillington Sure, I've edited my answer with a suggested solution

Comment: thank you for updating the question, it is definitely very helpful, however I am unsure of what to delete and where to add in that code

Comment: @MelissaChillington I have expanded on my answer further. If this works for you please mark this as the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: I changed it according to what you said but it didn't exactly work, I posted a screenshot in my question that shows what happened

Comment: when I remove the image tag off index.html it removes the image entirely even though I have it in my style.css

Answer (score 1):

Add this to prevent the default margin of the `body`element:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.headerC {
  background: #89cff0;
  font: 36pt/40pt courier;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0.1;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  border: thick dashed hotpink;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerC">
  <h1 align="center">Contact</h1>
  <h5 align="center"> <a href="tel:203-831-9722" class="link">203-831-9722</a></h5>
  <h5 align="center">234 East Ave 06855</h5>
  <h6 align="center">Norwalk, CT</h6>

</div>
```

Comment: It isn't working for me I can't figure out why because your solution works when I run the snippet here

Comment: Try using the inspector, it should tell you where the extra space is coming from