# Absolute positioned div is hidden when the sticky navbar is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, sticky

When my `navbar` touches the top of the screen, the links of the dropdown menu are disappearing.

I've used *w3schools* tutorials and examples to create my page. Especially:

- [howto: js_navbar_sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)
- [howto: css_dropdown_navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp)

This is the example of my problem:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navi");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#navi {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.drop {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drop .dropbutton {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar a:hover,
.drop:hover .dropbutton {
  background-color: #25aa25;
}

.links {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 210px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.links a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.links a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.drop:hover .links {
  display: block;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+article {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      Example for StackOverflow
    </h1>
  </header>
  <nav id="navi">
    <div class="drop">
      <button class="dropbutton">
                Button - dropdown
            </button>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="">Random link 1</a>
        <a href="">Random link 2</a>
        <a href="">Random link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
  </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct question would be "*Why we can see the dropdown when the `navbar` is not at the top of the screen?*".

The `navbar` has the CSS property `overflow` set to `hidden`, preventing content out of its boundaries to get visible. But the `div` containing the drop-down links (`.links`) has `position` set to `absolute`, so it is out of the document flow.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute):

> **`absolute`**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.

Because `.links` doesn't have any positioned ancestor, its position is relative to the initial containing block.

But when the `navbar` touches the top of the screen, the `.sticky` class gets applied. Its mainly function is to set the `position` CSS property to `fixed` (out of the document flow and positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport).

When `.sticky` is applied, `.links` **is positioned relative to `navbar`**, so it gets affected for `overflow: hidden`.

Because you don't need to hide it when `.sticky` applies, set the `overflow` property of the `navbar` to `visible` when that happens.

In CSS, the `id` attribute has priority over the `class` so you have two options. Update the `.sticky` class:

```
.sticky {
  ...
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

That will lead sooner or later to [an !important nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360237/5247200). Or much better, create a new rule containing both selectors to give it a higher priority:

```
#navi.sticky {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navi");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#navi.sticky {
  overflow: visible;
} 

#navi {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.drop {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drop .dropbutton {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar a:hover,
.drop:hover .dropbutton {
  background-color: #25aa25;
}

.links {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 210px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.links a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.links a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.drop:hover .links {
  display: block;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+article {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      Example for StackOverflow
    </h1>
  </header>
  <nav id="navi">
    <div class="drop">
      <button class="dropbutton">
                Button - dropdown
            </button>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="">Random link 1</a>
        <a href="">Random link 2</a>
        <a href="">Random link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
    <p>Just for filling in the page</p>
  </article>
</body>
```