# Can't style Fancybox modal

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having problems styling a modal I've set to open with fancy box. The content for the modal/div shows up after clicking with no issues but it seems all the styling I applied to that modal div refuses to show up.

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}

.red{
background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>modal</title>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
  
  
<body>
  <div>
     <a data-fancybox data-src="#open" href="javascript:;">Open modal  box</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hidden">
     <div class="red" id="open">
          <h2>Hello</h2>
          <p>You are awesome.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
  
</body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is my [setup](https://codepen.io/sdev01/pen/bGdpgqz?editors=1100) on Codepen

Comment: .red{ background: red !important;}

Comment: Your style is correct but Get it first priority for fancybox included style

Comment: !important also works but I wouldnt be able to use it for all the styling I needed to apply to the div. See Ritesh Khandekar's answer

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360237/10273906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your common selectors can't able to apply styles then try to select elements more specifically.

IDs are Higher specific because they are unique.

Class names are specific too but they are used in other stylesheets also

Tag names are not most specific because they can found anywhere in page

And `*` selector has lowest specificity in css

```
div.red{background: red;} // Selects divs that have 'red' classname
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}

div.red{
background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>modal</title>
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
</head>
  
  
<body>
  <div>
     <a data-fancybox data-src="#open" href="javascript:;">Open modal  box</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hidden">
     <div class="red" id="open">
          <h2>Hello</h2>
          <p>You are awesome.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
  
</body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox adds `fancybox-content` classname to the content to add some necessary CSS properties and some default styling, for example, white background color, padding.

Therefore you simply override these rules, example:

```
.fancybox-content.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```