# Changing styles of bootstrap .btn-success and .btn-warning buttons not working in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, bootstrap-4

Inside my meteor application, I tried to change the colour of bootstrap 4.5 .btn-warning and .btn-success buttons to have other colours. But none of my styles which I applied into the main.css files is working, whereas the styles on the other elements of the same css file works properly.

Here are the styles I applied :

```
.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #20ad00;
  border-color: #20ad00;
}

.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f36a02d1;
  border-color: #ffa04d;
}
```

While not working, I finally copied all the .btn and .btn-success .btn-warning styles from the browser console development tool, replaced the classes with btn-success-sitename and btn-warning-sitename, and pasted the copied styles respectively to the new classes in myy css file. But I think there's a better way to do it.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps the css inspector might show what's overriding it? May need a higher specificity perhaps.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to use the css inspector ? I don't know a lot about.

Comment: I am not recommend overriding to boostrap  class . Because it all style have related to each other . So add your custom class and use it .

Comment: @DavidJawHpan Yes, and I would like to add that adding styles to a class alone could possibly not work, so either the custom stylesheet has to be loaded after the bootstrap css stylesheet or maybe inline that custom CSS.

Comment: @RaoulHouessou for the Dev Tools in Chrome see here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: Do you use the Meteor default css or a sass compilers for processing styles? I recommend using the sass compiler in order to customize bootstrap themes. I can create an answer if you like

Comment: I don't see any reason why it doesn't work if you overwrite the `bootstrap` classes with yours in your customized `css` file. You could use `scss` to force this. And in other hand I would recommend to not use `id`.

Comment: Ok I'll keep my custom class so. Thank you @DavidJawHpan

Comment: @Jankapunkt I use default css, not sass. You think sass will do the job ? Ok I'll like to see your answer.

Comment: @k.vincent how to use scss to force it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So either as suggested David add an id to the elements and write that code for these new IDs. They will override styles contained inside the boostrap classes b/c IDs have higher specificity.

```
<button class="btn-success" id="custom-button-1">Click here</button>
```

And then in your CSS

```
#custom-button-1 {
background:blue}
```

Otherwise, you could try adding !important at the end of your style statements, it should override the BS styles too, like this:

```
.btn-success {
background:blue!important}
```

Comment: Understood @LaurentC. I didn't know about !important overriding role. And I was avoiding having same id for many elements in my page. I know what to do now.

Comment: @RaoulHouessou: You could use: `!important` but this could also cause you some issues under some circumstances e.g. when you once need to use some customized classes in for the same element/tag with different styles depending on you concept: `<button class="btn-success btn-register-success" ...>`. This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property) might give you a better Idea what I'am talking about. For now it would fix your issue but I would keep in mind to maintain the `css` and the classes with `!important` once the app become complicated.

Comment: @k.vincent: Got it