# Override css without using !important - Semantics UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, overriding, semantic-ui

I'm using styled components to style a table with the Semantics UI kit framework within react.

This piece of code gives me the desired look i want, spacing table rows:

```
const MembersTable = styled(Table)({
borderSpacing: "0 1em !important",
border: "none !important",
width: "75vw !important",  
});
```

However, I do not want to use !important to override the css.

I have this code but it does not seem to work:

```
const MembersTable = styled(Table)`
&&&
{
    borderSpacing: "0 1em";
    border: "none";
    width: "75vw";
}
`;
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get my desired effect without using !important? Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use `!important` ?

Comment: makes debugging more difficult

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property

Comment: have you tried increasing the specificity, that's the only way other than using !important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was using Semantics styling variables, and not using the default css styling variables. I also did not want to use !important after referring to this post: [Is it bad to use !important in css property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property)

```
const MembersTable = styled(Table)`
&&&{
    border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI tries to give you all of the possible variations so that you can always choose from the given options. Unfortuntely, there are several times that those options are not enough, so in these cases you just have 2 options, either to use `!important` or to give the element styles with a more specific selector than the one from Semantic UI.