# How to Give less priority Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried so many times to give less priority of Bootstrap CSS but I am not able to give it.
I have placed my `custom.css` below the CDN link of Bootstrap

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Writing `!important` to all the CSS Properties would be a very hard task since I am working on a very big project which has many line of CSS Codes

Comment: Your homework: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: We cannot help more unless you supply some of the problematic css from `style.css`

Answer (score -1):

Why dont use `!important` instead on your custom.css?

> The !important rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a
> property/value than normal.
>
> In fact, if you use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous
> styling rules for that specific property on that element!

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Comment: !important as a tool of last resort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-a-css-property

Comment: [!important is valid CSS syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360363/7590238)  and there is nothing wrong with using it—provided you understand what it is doing and why it is solving your problem, so that you use it in the right way.