# MUI Textfield placeholder text color looks faded

Tags: material-ui

I have been trying to set the placeholder color for MUI TextField.

I could see the placeholder turning red with the styles i have added but the red color looks faded.

how do i style the placeholder so that the color looks solid.

```js
                            <TextField
                                placeholder="hello"
                                variant="outlined"
                                sx={{
                                    input: {
                                        color: 'red', // <----- i want it to be original red.
                                    },
                                    label: { color: 'blue' },
                                }}
                            />
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Some browsers (such as Firefox) set the default opacity of placeholders to something less than 100%.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder#opaque_text

So, you should set `opacity` of `placeholder` to `1`

```
<TextField
   placeholder="hello"
   variant="outlined"
   sx={{
      input: {
         color: 'red',
         "&::placeholder": {    // <----- Add this.
            opacity: 1,
         },
      },
      label: { color: 'blue' }
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or CSS if you want clean code:

```
.input{
    :last-child{
        font-size: 20px !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        &::placeholder{
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: from experience, its not always very nice to use important. you can see the other accepted answer without the use of important.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360330/4758148 good explanation for both worlds in this answer