# Why my CSS custom Google font is not working normal?

Tags: html, css, fonts, frameworks, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and I have embedded the link to google fonts in my html file and I want to change the font-family in css file and it is not working the way I want to!
Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <h1 id="entryHeading">Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#entryHeading{
    font-family: "Montserrat-Black" sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;

}
```

It is working in a sense that, It is changing my font to Montserrat but I want Montserrat-Black which is not working!
Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `!important` to the font-family. This will overwrite the bootstrap fonts by force.

```
#entryHeading{
font-family: "Montserrat-Black" sans-serif !important;
font-size: 3rem;
line-height: 1.5;
```

}

**NB: don't try this :) "!important" is bad**

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Careful about unreflected recommendations! --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-a-css-property

Comment: Always consider the consequences as well as alternatives. --> https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/

Comment: @jasie thank you for pointing out my mistakes. I'll do more detailed research before giving someone advice. :D

Answer (score -1):

You are missing comma ' , ' between font names

CSS

```css
#entryHeading{
    font-family: "Montserrat-Black", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: It's not working