# Change appearance on multiple buttons on focus

Tags: javascript

I have this part of my site where i'm using javascript to show and hide a div when clicked, so far so good, my problem is i want the color of the button to change when clicked, so that the color in ".steg1" changes to #CCA200 when i click ".steg2".

I have tried focus, but I have more places on the same page where I need to use this so I'm looking for a different solution. I've tried some jquery with no luck, is this doable in javascript?

here is the code:

```html
<button class="steg1" onclick="myFunctionq();">
1 - TECKNA MOBILABONNEMANG
</button>

<style>
  .steg1 {
    font-family: 'mark-heavy';
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 5px;
    color: #223137;
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function myFunctionq() {
    var x =
      document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
    var y =
      document.getElementById("tecknael");
    var z =
      document.getElementById("rabatt");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<button class="steg2" onclick="myFunctionp()">
2 - TECKNA ELAVTAL
</button>

<style>
  .steg2 {
    font-family: 'mark-heavy';
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 5px;
    padding: 0 60px;
    color: #CCA200;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function myFunctionp() {
    var x =
      document.getElementById("tecknael");
    var y =
      document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
    var z =
      document.getElementById("rabatt");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<button class="steg3" onclick="myFunctionr(); buttonColorb()">
3 - FÅ RABATT PÅ ELEN
</button>

<style>
  .steg3 {
    font-family: 'mark-heavy';
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 5px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    color: #CCA200;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function myFunctionr() {
    var x =
      document.getElementById("rabatt");
    var y =
      document.getElementById("tecknael");
    var z =
      document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Ok, i've gotten it to work to almost perfection, I only need to when step1 is pressed after the other steps, it stays black, how do i put so that "if this is .focused then it should be .colored? here is the updated code.

```
<button id="step1button" class="step1" onclick="step1Click();">
1 - TECKNA MOBILABONNEMANG
</button>

<style>
#step1button {
font-family:'mark-heavy';
font-size:16px;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
border-bottom:solid 5px;
color:#223137;
padding: 0 40px;
}
</style>

<script>
function step1Click() {
var x =
document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
var y =
document.getElementById("tecknael");
var z =
document.getElementById("rabatt");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
y.style.display = "none";
z.style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('step1button').classList.add('focused');
  document.getElementById('step3button').classList.remove('focused');
  
  document.getElementById('step2button').classList.remove('focused');
}
  
</script>

<button id="step2button" class="step2" onclick="step2Click()">
2 - TECKNA ELAVTAL
</button>

<style>
#step2button {
font-family:'mark-heavy';
font-size:16px;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
border-bottom: solid 5px;
padding:0 60px;
color:#CCA200;
}
</style>

<script>
function step2Click() {
var x =
document.getElementById("tecknael");
var y =
document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
var z =
document.getElementById("rabatt");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
y.style.display = "none";
z.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('step1button').classList.add('colored');
  document.getElementById('step3button').classList.remove('focused');
  
  document.getElementById('step2button').classList.add('focused');
}
</script>

<button id="step3button" class="step3" onclick="step3Click(); colorchange()">
3 - FÅ RABATT PÅ ELEN
</button>

<style>
#step3button {
font-family:'mark-heavy';
font-size:16px;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
border-bottom: solid 5px;
padding: 0 50px;
color:#CCA200;
}
  
  .colored {
    color:#CCA200 !important;
  }
  .focused {
    color:#223137 !important;
  }
</style>

<script>
function step3Click() {
var x =
document.getElementById("rabatt");
var y =
document.getElementById("tecknael");
var z =
document.getElementById("tecknamobil");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
y.style.display = "none";
z.style.display = "none";

document.getElementById('step1button').classList.add('colored'); 

  document.getElementById('step3button').classList.add('focused');
  
  document.getElementById('step2button').classList.remove('focused');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually handle things like this is create another class let's say `.colored` which has `color: #CCA200` in it, then `add`/`remove`/`toggle` the class from the element whenever you want, this way you can add it to more than one element as well if needed, so you don't have to rewrite it every time.

```js
// When ".steg2" is clicked
function myFunctionp() {
  document.getElementById('steg1').classList.toggle('colored');
}
```

```css
.colored {
  color: #CCA200;
}
```

```html
<!-- Added an id to find it easier -->
<button class="steg1" onclick="myFunctionq();" id='steg1' >
1 - TECKNA MOBILABONNEMANG
</button>
```

For the updated question: You added `.colored` and `.focused`, you only really need one of them, so in CSS you should make the initial color of the buttons `#CCA200`, and then add/remove the `.focused` class based on which button is clicked:

```js
function step1Click() {
  
  ...
  
  // step1Click should add focus to step1button and remove it from the others
  // Then you just repeat this pattern for step2Click and step3Click.
  document.getElementById('step1button').classList.add('focused');
  document.getElementById('step2button').classList.remove('focused');
  document.getElementById('step3button').classList.remove('focused');
}
```

```css
#step1button {
  color: #CCA200;
  ...
}

#step2button {
  color: #CCA200;
  ...
}

#step3button {
  color: #CCA200;
  ...
}

.focused {
  color: #223137;
}
```

Comment: There are very few places where `!important` is a good choice, and this really doesn't require it.

Comment: I mean you're right, I guess, I'll edit it, but I do usually use it in classes like these that are added/removed in some way. Is there something I'm unaware of that can go horribly wrong?

Comment: Here's a question with answers that explain it far better than I could in a character-limited comment: [Is it bad to use !important in a CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-a-css-property)

Comment: Added an update, any ideas to how i can fix the final problem? @JánosAracsi

Comment: Thank you! the only thing is that i need "step1" to be .focused from the beginning. so that when i first open the page, step 1 is focused and the other steps are #CCA200, and then the button i press from there on is the only one .focused

Comment: Then just add `.focused` to `.step1` in the html from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we should rename your functions to be more specific. Also, I would recommend writing everything code related in English rather than Swedish.

So this will be the HTML markup.

```
<button id="step2button" class="step2" onclick="step2Click()">
  2 - TECKNA ELAVTAL
</button>

<button class="step3" onclick="step3Click()">
  3 - FÅ RABATT PÅ ELEN
</button>
```

You will need to adjust CSS to match the new classes `step` instead of `steg`.

And for the JavaScript, rename the functions to match the new names in the markup. And add the following line to `step3Clicked`.

```
var step2button = document.getElementById("step2button");
step2button.display.backgroundColor = "#CCA200";
```