# How to remove underline from a link in HTML?

Tags: html

In my page I have put some links under which I don't want any line, so, how can I remove that using HTML?

Comment: Paic, I'm not going to bother rolling back the tags again, but just so you know, the only way to remove the underline is **with CSS**. Yes, even though you're adding it inline with the HTML (in the `style` attribute), *it is still CSS*. The other two tags are also completely valid (`presentation` and `hyperlink`). In the future, please don't remove (or add) tags to a question unless there is a valid reason to do so. Thanks!

Comment: @bfrohs I respect your words but I am building my site using only HTML and so I did not add more tags because if I would have did so, I might have got answers for different language. Actually I am a bit novice to it, that's the reason.

Comment: You cannot build a standards-compliant website without CSS (unless you go with browser defaults for all presentation). HTML = structure; CSS = presentation. The other tags had nothing to do with a different language - they were only provided to help people find the question and answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the underline for anchors(links)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks)

Comment: Why does this question have so many up votes? You can literally answer it in a single Google search and I'm sure there are many duplicates of it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

[Inline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp) version:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/" style="text-decoration:none">yoursite</a>
```

However remember that you [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties) generally [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142710/inline-styles-vs-classes) the content of your website (which is [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)), from the presentation (which is [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)). Therefore you should generally [avoid inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css).

See [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853894/1321680) to see equivalent answer using [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks).

Comment: killer! I never saw these underscore lines in all the years that I where doing html.... ^^

Comment: John's answer still uses essentially inline styles. Separating your CSS means more than aliasing css in your html. Eg `class="big-and-red"` is aliasing not seperation. `class="meaningful-domain-item"` then css `.meaningful-domain-item { //big and red }` is. This answer sufficient to remind me which tag to use in my css +1.

Comment: This above-mentioned code did not work for me. When I dig into the problem I realize that it was not working because I'd placed the style after the href. When I placed the style before the href it was working as expected.

<a href="http://yoursite.com/" style="text-decoration:none">yoursite</a>

Answer (score 62):

This will remove all underlines from all links:

```
a {text-decoration: none; }
```

If you have specific links that you want to apply this to, give them a class name, like `nounderline` and do this:

```
a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
```

That will apply only to those links and leave all others unaffected.

This code belongs in the `<head>` of your document or in a stylesheet:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
    </style>
</head>
```

And in the body:

```
<a href="#" class="nounderline">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 21):

I suggest to use :hover to avoid underline if mouse pointer is over an anchor

```
a:hover {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Add this to your external style sheet (**preferred**):

   ```css
   a {text-decoration:none;}
   ```
2. Or add this to the `<head>` of your HTML document:

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration:none;}
   </style>
   ```
3. Or add it to the `a` element itself (*not recommended*):

   ```html
   <!-- Add [ style="text-decoration:none;"] -->
   <a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration:none;">Text</a>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers all mention text-decoration. Sometimes you use a Wordpress theme or someone else's CSS where links are underlined by other methods, so that text-decoration: none won't turn off the underlining.

Border and box-shadow are two other methods I'm aware of for underlining links. To turn these off:

```
border: none;
```

and

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 4):

All the above-mentioned code did not work for me. When I dig into the problem I realize that it was not working because I'd placed the style after the href. When I placed the style before the href it was working as expected.

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://yoursite.com/">yoursite</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

**The following is not a best practice, but can sometimes prove useful**

It is better to use the solution provided by John Conde, but sometimes, using external CSS is impossible. So you can add the following to your HTML tag:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style="text-decoration: none">
```

The above code will be enough.Just paste this into the link you want to remove underline from.