# using image that I have its url in database for background image

Tags: php, html, css, styles, background-image

I'm designing a web page to show some commodity
results (such Model, price, Comment) for every Commodity is a database
and I call theme to show in each Commodity (it while be shown in a div)
I wanna to set backgrounds for each div (it saved in database and every Commodity have one background-image)
please tell me whats the true syntax for this div s
for example I wrote this code:

```
<div class="commodities"> <style>.commodities{ background-image:<?php $Images[$i]?>}  </style>
<?php
    echo "Model:";
    echo $Models[$i];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $Prices[$i];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $Comments[$i];

?>
</div>
```

please help me to fix this part of code: { background-image:}

Comment: You need to learn how to do inline styling with html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties

Comment: You can't put a `<style>` inside the `<body>`. That has to go up into the `<head>` part of the site. Or do as @Pitchinnate suggested and do it with inline styles on the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
    <div class="commodities" style="background-image: url('<?php $Images[$i]?>');">
<?php
    echo "Model:";
    echo $Models[$i];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $Prices[$i];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $Comments[$i];

?>
</div>
```

If you put **< style >** tags in the **< body >** (put it on the **< head >** tags) you are doing nothing ;)

Instead use **style** property. ;)

Apart you are forgetting to use *url tag* on the **background-image** property. ;)

Comment: tnx for ur answer but it doesnt work:(
i tested Imeges array whit printing and it works probably but Icant set it for background image!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two keywords, scoped and url. See e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I think your original question has been answered, and perhaps you should go back to reading some tutorials/books and come again with a spesific new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

use inline css.

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $variable_name; ?>);">
```

or
use internal css.

```
<style type="text/css">
.logo {
background: #FFF url(<?php echo $variable_name; ?>);
}
</style>
```