# HTML space tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a web page using HTML and I want to add space between the components say between `div1` and `div2`.

Is there any tag like space in HTML so that I can use

```
 <space width="50px" height="10px"/>
```

or what is the best way to add space?

```
<div class="hrz-group" id="div1">
    <label>Attribute:</label>
    <select>
        <option id="day" value="month">Day</option>
        <option id="week" value="week">Week</option>
        <option id="month" value="month">Month</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="hrz-group">             
    <label class="hrz-group" id="div2" > Type:</label>
    <select class="hrz-group">
        <option id="Bar" value="Bar">Bar</option>
        <option id="Line" value="Line">Line</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use margins

Comment: ... or another accordingly sized `<div>` if you plan to style your space.

Comment: ... or a table layout. haha, just kidding, put down the torches and the pitchforks guys!

Comment: I would avoid adding extra markup if you don't need it (makes the page heavier, slower to load unnecessarily) - if you can use margins and paddings (via CSS) the you should. my 2 cents.

Comment: CSS margins are the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `<spacer>` tag if CSS margins don't do what you want.

I never use it (I use CSS), so I can't talk to how well it's supported across browsers.

[Spacer tag tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_spacer_tag.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques people have used over the years to accomplish this task.  Off the top of my head:

[CSS Margin/Padding](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/)  - This is typically the easiest, most semantically correct way to introduce spacing into your dom elements (also very common, which means the people that come in after you will like you more).

[Dimensional Class Names](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/fight-div-itis-and-class-itis-with-the-960-grid-system/) - Create a series of descriptive class names that can be used throughout your codebase (technique relied on by most css grid systems). Useful for setting dimensions on any element, blank or not (especially handy for tabular data needs where tables/divs aren't cooperating)

```
    <style type='text/css'>
      .w50px{width:50px}
      .h10px{width:10px}
    </style>

    <div class='w50px h10px'></div>
```

[Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013573/183624) - Manually decorate elements in your page with inline styles for fine-tuned control. Note that this is generally frowned upon because it mixes content/design concerns and requires manual intervention to change (which is painful in scenarios where you need to change values across the site).

```
    `<div style='display:inline-block;width: 20px;"></div>`
```

[Spacer Images](http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/~petrie/jump3a.htm) - Use an X-by-Y pixel image to put space between elements. This is getting oldschool and isn't really used any more (CSS has come a long way since the 90's)

```
   <span>My Content></span><img src="10x30.gif"/><span>More Content</span>
```

See Also:
[Fighting the Spaces](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS Margins

```
.space-below {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and add that class to the top `.hrz-group`

```
<div class="hrz-group space-below" id="div1">...
```

**OR** (though I don't like styling on ids*)

```
#div1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Or, if you don't have your styles separate yet, put `margin-bottom: 10px;` in the style attribute of the first `div`.

*[This article by Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/a-line-in-the-sand/) is really good, and links to some other great things covering ids vs. classes.