# PHP if else condition on validation

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an activation page that will GET the API & ACT codes from the url.

Then I am trying to query the DB on those codes to check if they're valid.

If they are not valid, I would like to echo an error stating `echo "<strong><font color=red>Your Activation Code has Expired, or Your Activation Code is not Valid!</font></strong>";`

If it is valid, then I would like to update with the `2nd SQL Query - "UPDATE users SET status='1', date_activated='$Activation_Date', Activation='' WHERE Activation='$Activation' AND API='$API' AND status='0'"`

If there is NO API&ACT code in the URL, I would like to echo "CONTENT"

```
   <?
    require 'admin/config.php';
    require 'Connection.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $API = $_REQUEST['api'];
    $Activation = $_REQUEST['act'];

    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE Activation='$Activation'");

    if ($sql = 0) { echo"ERROR";}
    else {
    $Activation_Date = date('m-j-y - h-iA');
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                        SET status='1', date_activated='$Activation_Date', Activation='' 
                        WHERE Activation='$Activation' AND API='$API' AND status='0'");
    if($sql == 0){
        echo "<strong><font color=red>Your Activation Code has Expired, or Your Activation Code is not Valid!</font></strong>";
    } elseif ($sql > 0) {
    echo "content";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: ok, so is there a problem with your code? you only state that you'd like to show one message or the other. besides this `if ($sql = 0)` which is incorrect, you fail to actually fetch here.

Comment: I am having difficulty instructing it correctly to do as I want. I've gotten this far with it, but stuck now. It just keeps displayign success. Even if there isnt the keys in the url. I fairly green :( @Fred-ii-

Comment: Trying to do if ($Activation & $API) is valid in the url, then execute the query to the database to validate if the API key is still active (has not been activated). If it is not active I would like it to echo "not valid", if it is active and then echo "content". If no API & Activation is in the url echo "error"  ---- IF the Activation code is active (the md5 has will be there) if its not active it will be default `NULL` @Fred-ii-

Comment: I posted something for you below.

Comment: Your code is extremely prone to SQL injection btw. Someone could input the activation code: ' or 1=1 LIMIT '1    to always return 1 row and pass the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with.

This is a Tweak from @hherger's answer....

```
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Get parameters and check if mandatory parameters are set // Get parameters and check if mandatory parameters are set
$API =        isset($_REQUEST['api']) ? $_REQUEST['api'] : false;
$Activation = isset($_REQUEST['act']) ? $_REQUEST['act'] : false;
if ( ($API===false) || ($Activation===false)) {

}

// Select activation record
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Activation='$Activation'");
if ($sql===false) { 
    echo "SQL ERROR: " . mysql_error(); 
    return;
} else {
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    mysql_free_result($sql);
    if ($nrows < 1) { 
        // No matching record found
        echo "REDIRECT USER TO HOME PAGE"; 
        return;
    } else {
        // Update users record
        $Activation_Date = date('m-j-y - h-iA');
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                SET status='1', date_activated='$Activation_Date', Activation='' 
                WHERE pinAPP_Activation='$Activation' AND API='$API' AND status='0'");
        if ($sql===false) {
            echo "SQL ERROR: " . mysql_error();
        } elseif(mysql_affected_rows() < 1) {
            // No matching record found for updating
            echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Your Activation Code has Expired, or Your Activation Code is not Valid!</span>';
        } else {
        echo "ECHO SUCCESS DISPLAY!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need to check for, is if a row exists.

To check if it exists and base yourself on the following model:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE Activation='$Activation'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    //do something here or show error because relation already exists
}
else{
   //relation already do not exists. so you can insert the record here
}
```

Then, to check if your UPDATE was truly successful, use `mysql_affected_rows()`:

Sidenote: This function may require that you pass a db connection variable to it.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users .... ");

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){

   // do something
   }

else {
   // do something else
   }
```

Check for errors against your PHP and MySQL:

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

If you get errors about deprecation notices, then you will need to switch over to either `mysqli_` or PDO.

You can consult one of my answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253579/1415724 to check if a row exists.

It uses a few methods, including a prepared statement which is something you should be using because you are open to an SQL injection.

Sidenote: The connection API that you are using is unknown. Make sure that you are using the same one as your query being `mysql_`. If it's `mysqli_` or PDO, those different APIs do not intermix. You must use the same one from connecting to querying.

Also, just a quick note about `if ($sql = 0)`. The single equal sign "assigns" instead of "comparing" such as `==` or `===`.

---

You stated in comments:

> *"IF the Activation code is active (the md5 has will be there)"*

I hope you're not using that for password storage. If so, don't. That function is no longer safe to use to store passwords with.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

Seeing `<?` make sure that short tags are enabled. If not, change that to `<?php`.

**HTML stickler.**

`<font color=red>` the `<font>` tag is deprecated/obsole and isn't supported by HTML5.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

It's best to use inline CSS if you are sending anything via Email.

I.e.: `<p style="color:red;">Hello world</p>`

Here are a few references:

- http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php
- [Inline <style> tags vs. inline css properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties)
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm

Comment: the Activation code isn't a password. Its just a random generated number when the user registers to validate their email address.

Comment: @Levi Ok, I wasn't sure of that, since you did mention a "hash".

Comment: No worries. I will try to puzzle this together shortly. I will update you on my outcome and what I have if I run into any issues.

Comment: @Levi Also make sure that the columns are long enough to accommodate all data. MySQL will fail silently if that is the case, for the MD5 hash, etc.

Comment: @staypuftman thanks. I try to be as thorough as possible.

Answer (score 1):

### Remarks

- Checking mandatory parameters:
  You can test if parameters are set like this:
  **isset(variable_name)**.
- In the SELECT query there is **missing the FROM clause** which states the table to select from.
  I assume it is "user" like in the UPDATE query.
- After a SELECT query, the cursor should be freed again, when it is no longer in use: **mysql_free_result($sql);**

### (Error) Tests

- The result of a query is **===false** if the query could not be executed corectly.
- After having SELECTed records, the function **mysql_num_rows()** shows the number or records retrieved.
- After having UPDATed a table, the function **mysql_affected_rows()** gives the number of affected records.

### Code snippet

```
// Get parameters and check if mandatory parameters are set
$API =        isset($_REQUEST['api']) ? $_REQUEST['api'] : false;
$Activation = isset($_REQUEST['act']) ? $_REQUEST['act'] : false;
if ( ($API===false) || ($Activation===false)) {
    $which =  ($API === false ) ? '"api"' : '';
    $which .= ($Activation === false) ? ((empty($which) ? '' : ', ') . '"act"') : '';
    echo "ERROR: Parameter(s) missing: $which";
    return;
}

// Select activation record
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Activation='$Activation'");
if ($sql===false) { 
    echo "SQL ERROR: " . mysql_error(); 
    return;
} else {
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows();
    mysql_free_result($sql);
    if ($nrows < 1) { 
        // No matching record found
        echo "ERROR: No activation record found"; 
        return;
    } else {
        // Update users record
        $Activation_Date = date('m-j-y - h-iA');
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users 
                SET status='1', date_activated='$Activation_Date', Activation='' 
                WHERE Activation='$Activation' AND API='$API' AND status='0'");
        if ($sql===false) {
            echo "SQL ERROR: " . mysql_error();
        } elseif(mysql_affected_rows() < 1) {
            // No matching record found for updating
            echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Your Activation Code has Expired, or Your Activation Code is not Valid!</span>';
        } else {
        echo "content";
        }
    }
}
```