# Trying to access appended element in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

```
    var count=3;
    socket.once('temp', function(temp){
      for (var i= 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
      $('#graphs').append('<div class= "myDiv2"' id="myDiv' + count + '" position:"relative;" style="width: 85%; height: 550px;">hi</div>');
      count++;
    };
  });
    var plotDiv2 = $('#myDiv3');
    console.log(plotDiv2);
```

When i try to print this appended div out, nothing prints out? How do I correctly access the appended div?

Comment: Your comment does not make sense to me.

Comment: To start with... the ID of your appended div isn't `#myDiv3`, it's `#myDiv`.  And your single and double quotes are completely messed up, not sure if it's a typo from your post or if that's really what your code looks like.  Also, what does the markup actually say when you right click -> inspect in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your quotes are mismatched. Notice the syntax color-coding in your post.
As such, the code throws a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here's a valid version:

```js
var count = 3,
    html = '<div class= "myDiv2" id="myDiv' + count + '" position:"relative;" style="width:50px; height:50px;">hi</div>';

jQuery('body').append(html);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

However, to simplify things, I suggest using jQuery to [create the new element](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#entry-examples-1), rather than directly concatenating an HTML string.

I also suggest including your CSS definitions as an [external style sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_sheet_(web_development)) rather than as inline styles directly in your HTML. See [Inline  tags vs. inline css properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties) for more reference.

```js
var $graphs=jQuery('#graphs');

for (var count = 3; count < 5; count++) {

  jQuery('<div>', {
    'class': 'myDiv',
       'id': 'myDiv' + count,
     'text': 'hi ('+count+')'
  }).appendTo($graphs);

};

var plotDiv2 = $('#myDiv3')
console.log(plotDiv2.prop('id'));
```

```css
.myDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="graphs"></div>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery#answer-4158203) for another example.