# Does CSS code initialize .style properties of DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

**Background:**

I created a simple DOM event example: see [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vgwfL3L1/4/).

```
<div id="squirrel" onmouseover="toggleFloat(this)">
    <p>Click me!</p>
</div>

<script>
    function toggleFloat(ele){
        var current = ele.style.cssFloat;
        console.log("cssFloat: "+current);
        if(current==="left")
            ele.style.cssFloat="right";
        else
            ele.style.cssFloat="left";
    }
</script>
```

Accompanying css:

```
#squirrel{
  float:left;
}
```

Odd behaviour was noticed: In the DOM, the #squirrel's initial value for the cssFloat property was "". (Open the developer console to see this. Or notice that the #squirrel doesn't move until the second event fires.).

**My question is:** Should the CSS code not have initialized the cssFloat property of the DOM object?  ...or any of the style properties for that matter?

Comment: The `style` property of an element represents its inline style  (defined with the `style`attribute). Those are not modified by the css rules defined in a your css file. The browser computes the final style based on those rules and the inline style. The final computed style can be retrieved using [`MDN: Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Yep! Doing the style inline [works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/vgwfL3L1/6/). (Post your comment as an answer so I can select it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` property of an element represents its inline style (defined with the `style` attribute).

Those are not modified by the css rules defined in a your css file. The browser computes the final style based on those rules and the inline style.

The final computed style can be retrieved using [MDN: Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

You generally should avoid to use inline style attributes. Normally you should try to use `class` to manipulate the appearance of a certain element. Also the use of the `style` property to dynamically change the inline style should only be used if there is really no way around it, e.g. if you need to move an element dynamically. You could also read the answer to [Inline  tags vs. inline css properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013573/1960455) for more informations.

Answer (score 2):

CSS *never* modifies the DOM.

The 'style' attributes in the DOM are merged-with/override the CSS defined in stylesheets.