# How to fetch html style properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dom element like this.

```
<div class="MyClass" id="123" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;">
    <div class="loading-indicator">loading...</div>
</div>
```

I want to take a width from tag `div` which is 228 and store in some variable which I can use later.

`var st = 228px; // dynamically`

Here I wanted to use.

```
var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
secondDiv.style = "background-color:#2C8DC2;color:white;padding:5px; margin-top:102px;height: 50px; width : st; border-style: solid;";
```

Now What I am trying here is :

var abc = firstDiv.getAttribute('style');

I am getting : `"width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;"`

`abc.width;`

But this is coming undefined.

How to fetch that value.

Comment: The [*style* property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is an object, not a string.

Comment: @RobG exactly, but it is coming as a string.

Comment: Yes,it is supposed to come as `string`. That's how they've designed it.

Comment: @David—when you use *getAttribute*, you get the value of the HTML attribute, which in many cases is different to the related property. The value returned by the ***style* property** is an **object**, it is a totally different value to the **string** returned by `getAttribute('style')`. See [*Does CSS code initialize .style properties of DOM objects?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234483/does-css-code-initialize-style-properties-of-dom-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this.

```
window.getComputedStyle(ele); gives you element style.
```

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("123"), // Do not use #
    eleStyle = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
/* Below is the width of ele */
var eleWidth = eleStyle.width;
console.log(eleWidth);
```

```html
<div class="MyClass" id="123" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;">
    <div class="loading-indicator">loading...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do

`alert($("#123").css("width")); // which will return 228px;`

```
<div class="MyClass" id="123" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;">
    <div class="loading-indicator">loading...</div>
</div>
```

if you still want to achieve it in straight javascript

use this reference : [How to get an HTML element's style values in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you use **jQuery**?

```js
console.log($(`#123`).css('width'));
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="MyClass" id="123" style="width: 228px; overflow: auto; height: 100px;">
    <div class="loading-indicator">loading...</div>
</div>
```