# Only CSS Carousel: problems with centering and fixing size

Tags: html, css, carousel

I have a carousel created with only CSS, but I have identified some difficulties. All images are in the 4:3 aspect ratio and may have a **maximum** of 640x480 px (that is, they can be smaller than this value), so:

- I can not center the next and previous arrows;
- The arrows can not be "floating" on the screen (if the next image is
  smaller than the previous one, the arrows should not change
  position);
- I do not know how to set the size of the carousel according to the
  largest image currently used.

The code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  padding: 2rem;

  background: #F8F8F8;

  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2rem;

  background: #FFF;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;

  max-width: 64rem;
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;

  background: red;

  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.group {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;

  background: blue;

  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.group input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;

  display: none;
}
.group input ~ .content {
  /* tentar fixar tamanho aqui */
  display: none;

  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  order: 2;
}
div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
  display: block;
}
div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
  display: block;
}
div.group label {
  top: 50%;

  display: none;

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  border: solid 1px black;

  background-color: #69C;

  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
label {
  margin: 125px 0 0 0;

  font-size: 4em;
}
label.previous {
  padding: 0 0 30px 5px;

  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  order: 1;
}
label.next {
  padding: 0 5px 25px 0;

  text-align: right;

  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Teste 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teste3.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="group">
                <input type="radio" name="test" id="0" value="0">
                <label for="4" class="previous">&lt;</label>
                <label for="1" class="next">&gt;</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png" width="200" height="286">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="radio" name="test" id="1" value="1">
                <label for="0" class="previous">&lt;</label>
                <label for="2" class="next">&gt;</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="https://www.ausmedia.com.au/Mmedia/4TO3.gif" width="200" height="139">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="radio" name="test" id="2" value="2">
                <label for="1" class="previous">&lt;</label>
                <label for="3" class="next">&gt;</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~cpi/images/photo_4-3.jpg" width="140" height="200">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="radio" name="test" id="3" value="3" checked="">
                <label for="2" class="previous">&lt;</label>
                <label for="4" class="next">&gt;</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.projectorcentral.com/images/articles/4-3%20Bristlecone%20Pines.jpg" width="200" height="287">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <input type="radio" name="test" id="4" value="4">
                <label for="3" class="previous">&lt;</label>
                <label for="0" class="next">&gt;</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="http://www.wallpaperawesome.com/wallpapers-awesome/wallpapers-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome/wallpaper-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome-951.jpg" width="96" height="139">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me find a solution or at least a **balance** in the measurements?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood,

You did not add 
`position: absolute` to labels. 
changed top to 18% to have them in center.
prev with `left:0;`
next with `right:0;`

This will set your labels as per the carousel, as it has the position relative.

```css
html{
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.wrap {
  max-width: 70rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #FFF;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 64rem;
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.group {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.group input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  display: none;
}
.group input ~ .content {
  /* tentar fixar tamanho aqui */
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  order: 2;
}
div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
  display: block;
}
div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
  display: block;
}
div.group label {
  position:absolute;
  top: 18%;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #69C;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
label {
  margin: 125px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 4em;
}
label.previous {
  padding: 0 0 30px 5px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  order: 1;
  left:0;
}
label.next {
  padding: 0 5px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  order: 3;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Teste 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teste3.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="0" value="0">
        <label for="4" class="previous">&lt;</label>
        <label for="1" class="next">&gt;</label>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png" width="200" height="286">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="1" value="1">
        <label for="0" class="previous">&lt;</label>
        <label for="2" class="next">&gt;</label>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="https://www.ausmedia.com.au/Mmedia/4TO3.gif" width="200" height="139">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="2" value="2">
        <label for="1" class="previous">&lt;</label>
        <label for="3" class="next">&gt;</label>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~cpi/images/photo_4-3.jpg" width="140" height="200">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="3" value="3" checked="">
        <label for="2" class="previous">&lt;</label>
        <label for="4" class="next">&gt;</label>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="http://www.projectorcentral.com/images/articles/4-3%20Bristlecone%20Pines.jpg" width="200" height="287">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="4" value="4">
        <label for="3" class="previous">&lt;</label>
        <label for="0" class="next">&gt;</label>
        <div class="content">
          <img src="http://www.wallpaperawesome.com/wallpapers-awesome/wallpapers-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome/wallpaper-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome-951.jpg" width="96" height="139">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was using this before, but, as you can see, when we go to bigger images, the arrows are floating in the screen again when the image size changes.

Comment: could you explain what do you want to achieve? may be a rough sketch of how do you want the arrows positioned irrespective of the image size will do.

Comment: I don't if it's possible, but I wanted that the CSS recognized the bigger image in the carousel at that moment and then use it as the max-height of this particular carousel. This way, I can fix the size and all other images will be centralized. Here is an image: [link](http://bashooka.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/css3-slider-2.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues with your code Bianca. First off when we write HTML, it's best to leave out `width` and `height` properties within the actual `html`. The reason for this is that the browser will consider anything in your `html` as more important than external `css` files. We call this `inline-styling` or `inline-styles` when `CSS` is written directly into `HTML`. (Here's a good explanation of the hierarchy of `CSS`: [Inline <style> tags vs. inline css properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties) )

Secondly, I updated your code, and included a `max-width` property to the `content` div, wherein your images are wrapped (the controlling `css`). So you can set that max-width to whatever you need, and it happens to work in this case.

Here's a Codepen: http://codepen.io/0rfila/pen/JbKrwj

And your updated code:

## CSS:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrap {
   max-width: 70rem;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 2rem;
   background: #FFF;
 }

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 64rem;
  min-height: 40rem;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.group {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

.group input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  display: none;
}
.group input ~ .content {
   /* tentar fixar tamanho aqui */
   display: none;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  order: 2;
}

div.group input:checked ~ div.content {
   display: block;
}
 div.group input:checked ~ label.previous,
 div.group input:checked ~ label.next {
 display: block;
}
div.group label {
  top: 50%;
  display: none; 
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #69C;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

label {
   margin: 125px 0 0 0;
   font-size: 4em;
 }
 label.previous {
   padding: 0 0 30px 5px;
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
   order: 1;
 }
 label.next {
  padding: 0 5px 25px 0;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  order: 3;
 }

.content {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Teste 3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teste3.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="group">
            <input type="radio" name="test" id="0" value="0">
            <label for="4" class="previous">&lt;</label>
            <label for="1" class="next">&gt;</label>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/photobatch/tutorials/img/scale_original.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="radio" name="test" id="1" value="1">
            <label for="0" class="previous">&lt;</label>
            <label for="2" class="next">&gt;</label>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="https://www.ausmedia.com.au/Mmedia/4TO3.gif">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="radio" name="test" id="2" value="2">
            <label for="1" class="previous">&lt;</label>
            <label for="3" class="next">&gt;</label>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~cpi/images/photo_4-3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="radio" name="test" id="3" value="3" checked="">
            <label for="2" class="previous">&lt;</label>
            <label for="4" class="next">&gt;</label>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://www.projectorcentral.com/images/articles/4-3%20Bristlecone%20Pines.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="radio" name="test" id="4" value="4">
            <label for="3" class="previous">&lt;</label>
            <label for="0" class="next">&gt;</label>
            <div class="content">
                <img src="http://www.wallpaperawesome.com/wallpapers-awesome/wallpapers-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome/wallpaper-for-monitor-4-3-almost-square-awesome-951.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, this may be a good solution, but the problem is that I can't control the size of the images they input in the carousel, except the max-width. So, if they add a very small image, it'll be incomprehensible. I can also fix the carousel to the max-width, but I'm thinking that if they only introduce small images, the carousel will be strangely large for it. What I really wanted is that the CSS recognized the bigger image in the carousel and use that specific width for this specific carousel, and so on.

Comment: Ahh so if they input a small image you would intend to have some background color there in place of the image? This wasn't clear before...

Comment: Yes! This is what I'm thinking of. I'm sorry, I'm not good explaining well what I'm thinking