# Resizing Window and Ensuring Image and text are all the right size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to maneuver around with the @media rule when resizing the screen

What I am trying to do is have an image take up 66.7% of the screen and text on the right to take the rest when I am on a big monitor. I have wrapped everything in a row then columns. When I resize my screen to a tablet size or mobile I want the image to take up 100% of the width and the text to display below the image and centered. My problem is not sure what size to exactly set it up to where the text column (col-lg-4) doesn't move just to the left hand side of the screen underneath the image when the screen is shrunk.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 img-example">            
       <div class="img-responsive" style="background-image: url(3.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 47.5% 42.675%; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-bottom: 80%; min-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="center-align">Hello</h3>
            <br />
            <h4 class="center-align">Hi</h4>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-example{
    width: 66.667%;
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .img-example {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;   
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px){
    .img-example .img-responsive{
        padding-bottom: 0!important;
        min-height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
}

.content {
padding: 150px 0 10px 0;
color: #c0d1ca
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No need for media query, bootstrap grid system is all you need.

> REF: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Also add `text-align: center;` to parent element will center the child. If you add `text-align: center;` to the child, it will not center itself.

```css
.img-example {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x500);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 47.5% 42.675%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding: 150px 0 10px 0;
  color: #c0d1ca;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 img-example">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 content">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
    <br />
    <h4>Hi</h4>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, just a quick question: Instead of calling for image in css, would it make a difference if I called it inside the div?

Comment: @Draklin try to use a stylesheet (faster), inline style is not recommended. for more you could read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties

Comment: @Draklin If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you! =D

Comment: Only reason I was asking is because I am having to run an IF statement inside my html code, incase I need to display a different image

Comment: @Draklin oh, take a look at this one, simple: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage

Comment: @Draklin I mean lots of site/project use inline-style if it is just you are doing a project, feel free to use it as long as it is working. For best practice, it is not recommended but it is not something wrong to do. Note that inline-style have the highest priority.