# Minor tweaks in reusable styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I've started using `styled-components` in one of my projects. I wanted to know the recommended way to override/extend them in the containers that use it.

Eg:

A reusable `Button` component :

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: red;
`;
```

Now suppose I am using this in a section, but need to apply a left margin. I can do this in a couple of ways:

**Extend:**

```
const NewButton = styled(Button)`
  margin-left: 10px;
`;
```

**Inline Style:**

```
<Button style={{marginLeft: '10px'}}>Normal Button</Button>
```

Extend looks like the best way to go if there are more than 3,4 rules to override.

But say for a single rule like `margin`, `padding`,`display: none` which may occur very frequently, creating a new wrapper each time adds to a lot of boilerplate. Inline styles work well on that aspect, but they have their own [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties).

What is the optimal approach that can scale well across large apps ?

Comment: this feels more like a software engineering SE question, but definitely either approach is valid. another option is to look at the context of your `marginLeft` button, do you really need all four margin variations on the button? or could you move that concern up a level to a container or parent element?

Comment: @worc Yes. But no matter where its moved to, even for a single variation, a new styled component would be required right ? Now imagine a form like structure, where there can be multiple containers & parents. Creating hocs for each element would be cumbersome as each parent might have a different layout.

Comment: not a higher order component, but a parent container with a simple css style for its immediate children

Comment: @worc : That defeats the purpose of using css-in-js ! I am so tempted to go that way, but resisting it to find some proper pattern within css-in-js.

Comment: the purpose of css-in-js is to reduce complexity, create narrow styling scopes, and offload naming conventions to the transpiler. letting an immediate parent handle spacing and margins still does all of those things.

Comment: Absolutely. But using a mix of both patterns sounds complicated. This is exactly what `emotion.sh` is doing. By providing a variety of apis to do all possible stuff. `styled-components` on the other hand provides a single api thereby restricting options, but at the same time enforcing some opinionated practices which I believe is good. Guess this is an open ended question then. I'll find the answer in good time.  :)

Comment: it doesn't have to be a mix of both patterns, the parent component handling spacing or margins is still a styled-component, and its css doesn't have to (and probably shouldn't) refer to exact children. you could use `& > *` [cautiously], or make it a flex container, or use padding or what have you. your scope is still narrow, and you're not necessarily introducing a big, complicated CSS tree.

Answer (score 0):

For styles that can vary slightly between usages, I recommend using the `props` object inside the style for calculating a property before it's defined.

With this, your buttons might look something like this:

```
// style that will always apply margin-left even if it doesn't exist
const Button = styled.button`
  margin-left: ${props => props.marginLeft}
`
// style that won't apply margin-left if it doesn't exist
const Button = styled.button`
  ${props => props.marginLeft && `
    margin-left: ${props.marginLeft};
  `}
`

// button with margin-left: 10px
<Button marginLeft="10px" />

// button without margin-left
<Button />
```

It's a little more work to implement this, but it's well worth it when styles can change between similar elements.

Comment: But will this be a sustainable approach ? There can be 4 variations of margin, padding. Not to mention other ad hoc styles such as `cursor: pointer`, `pointer-events: none`. Defining every such property in every component API could be tough.

Comment: I am specifically targeting layout style properties which are so many and cannot be anticipated while developing the component API. Hence a prop based approach feels unmaintainable.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way do what you're asking then. With styled components you have to know what properties you'll have on the element beforehand.

Comment: There are several ways. Just trying to find the right one :'). The best way I can see as of now is the `extend` method I had specified in the example.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding you then. By saying you can't anticipate the styles that will be applied during development I thought you meant you couldn't hard code them in any way. So there are other ways, but I doubt you'd find something any easier than this. I'll actually condense my answer a little so that it might be more fit.