# inline style vs className in Componet context

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, classname, inline-styles

Hello I try to understand when it's necessary to use `inline style` instead `className` in this case. I take a long time to solve my problem of translation. At the beginning I want to translate component by using `className`and that's don't work. it's very weird because in my point of view there is no reason that's happen. So I figure there is something wrong in my code, but what... I have not yet found. So I finish trying to translate by using a `inline style`. Miracle, that's work fine.

My question is why ?

Work well

```js
export function Content() {
  return (
        <div style={{transform: 'translateY(100px)'}}>
        <Test/>
        <Footer />
  </div>)
}
```

don't work

```js
export function Content() {
  return (
    <div className={container_content}>
        <Test/>
        <Footer />
        </div>
        )
}
```

css

```css
.container_content {
    transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

Nota bene :
The problem is not from the method. To use className in my `jsx`
must be like that:

```js
import { container_content } from "./test.module.css";
```

and next

```js
<div className={container_content}><div>
```

So this part of code is good, the issue seems to come from elsewhere...

Comment: It should be `<div className="container_content">`

Comment: related topic: CSS file VS inine styling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498259/1205684

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that when you use the inline style you are passing an object that includes the styling for that component. When you use the `className` you need to pass in a string for the class you want to use. Right now you are passing a variable name. Either of these works:

```
<div className={"container_content"}>
```

OR

```
<div className="container_content">
```

If you think about it in regular html you would do

```
<div class="container_content">
```

**EDIT:** Given your updated question, you should just import the css file with:

```
import "./test.module.css"
```

and then use the solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

inside the js file, you need to import the CSS file like this

> import " css-file-dir";

and then you can Reference to the CSS classes inside your component as a string

example :

```
className="container_content"
```