# Removing hyperlink underline also removes hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I import fontawesome icons.

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e5d9dacb14.js"></script>
```

Next, I have a hyperlink:

```
<a href="https://google.nl"> <i class="fa fa-user-o" ></i> Personal Page </a>
```

This hyperlink has the annoying underline, which I try to remove by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853881/how-to-remove-underline-from-a-link-in-html).

To do so, I add this to my css.

```
a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
```

And I change the hyperlink to:

```
<a.nounderline href="https://google.nl"> <i class="fa fa-user-o" ></i> Personal Page </a.>
```

Now. This does remove the underline, but it also removed the hyperlink. [See my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk8qpeot/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add class to your tag, add it by `class="nounderline"`

```css
a.nounderline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="nounderline" href="https://google.nl"> <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Personal Page </a>
```

Read more about [html classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) and [.class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`a.noundeline` represents an `a` that has `nounderline` for class.
So you have to create a `<a class="nounderline">` tag to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. You need to define `.nounderline` as a class in CSS.

```css
.nounderline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="nounderline" href="https://google.nl"> <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Personal Page </a.>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `text-decoration: none;` css style for Anchor tag. like below

```
a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have attached class name with HTML`<a>` tag that is wrong.

what you need to do is just add class property to your`<a>`tag like this:

```
<a class="nounderline"></a>

<a class="nounderline" href="https://google.nl"> <i class="fa fa-user-o" ></i> Personal Page </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this:

```
  a, nameofdiv{

color:black;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Hope this helps