# How to remove underline from links?

Tags: html

Is it possible to remove the underline when displaying a link on an html page.

```
<dt class="center">Value
<dt class="center"><a href="/test">Details</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove underline from a link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853881/how-to-remove-underline-from-a-link-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `text-decoration: none` in your CSS or styling.
It will remove the underline from your link:

```
a { text-decoration: none }
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `text-decoration:none`, it will remove underline.

```css
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<dt class="center">Value
<dt class="center"><a href="/test">Details</a>
```