# Hide Hyperlink Line using css

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, text-styling

I have this HTML Code

```
<a href="test.html">
<div class=" menubox mcolor1">
<h3>go to test page</h3>
</div>
</a>
```

and this is the css

```
.menubox {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #777;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    position: relative;}

.mcolor1 { background: #3A89BF url(../images/prod2.png) no-repeat center center; }
```

on mouse hover this div, the text shows the hyperlink line, how can I hide it?

Comment: `a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the underline for anchors(links)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks)

Comment: @Antony: I think there’s a little more to this question that the duplicate, given the HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have suggested, it's easy to remove the underline from links. However, if you need to target just this specific link, try giving it a class. Example:

```css
.no-underline:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="test.html" class="no-underline">
  <div class=" menubox mcolor1">
    <h3>go to test page</h3>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Working as Magic :)

Thank you ALL

Comment: still need 15 Rep points :( ...This is my first Q here :) ..I will do it once I gain some. Thx Nix and Thanks all.

Comment: You could alternatively move the `menubox` and `mcolor1` classes onto the `<a>`, and add `display:block;` and `text-decoration:none` to the `.menubox` style block. This would make the HTML a bit shorter

Comment: @Robinlolo: ah: you might need `.menubox:hover { text-decoration:none; }`, instead of adding `text-decoration:none` to the `.menubox` style block.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the underline on hover, use this CSS:

```
a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

#### Note :

Unless your page uses the HTML5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`), your HTML structure is invalid. Divs can't be nested inside `a` element before HMTL5.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But I can apply the href on the full div

Comment: @Morpheus: They can in the current version of HTML (HTML5). Try it: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Actually, in HTML5, you may nest block elements inside links. If it's anything other than HTML5, like XHTML or whatever, then it will be invalid, yes. http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Answer (score 1):

With the HTML as it stands, you can’t hide the link underline *just* for this link.

The following CSS will remove the underline for all links:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To remove it for just this link, you could move the link inside the `<div>`:

```css
.menubox > a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.menubox > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubox mcolor1">
    <a href="test.html">
        <h3>go to test page</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this one, and let you know. Thank you

Comment: I still want use my html structure

Comment: <a href="test.html">
<div class=" menubox mcolor1">
<h3>go to test page</h3>
</div>
</a>

In this case I can treat the Div as Button

Comment: You assume OP has control over the HTML. In that case, it might be better not to alter the structure, but to give the `<a>` a class, which may be targetted.

Comment: @Robinlolo: gotcha. I think keeping your original HTML is the better idea anyway — I’m not sure the `height:100%` in my CSS will work.

Comment: @Nix: I did assume that, although if he/she doesn’t control the HTML, he/she can’t give the link a class either.