# How to remove decoration in <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the decoration text in the `<p>` tag not to be overwritten by the `<a>` tag?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none !important
}

#paragraph {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph"><a href="#">this is a link</a></p>
```

My problem is that I want the text color p is black, not blue.

I found this one but no useful
   [How to remove the underline for anchors(links)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks)

Please guys explain this. All helps are appreciated.

Comment: `#paragraph a { color: black; }`

Comment: The blue color is from the :link pseudo-class, not a text-decoration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to use `inherit`, so it will depend on the parents property.

```
a { color: inherit; text-decoration: inherit }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<style>` tag, change `a` with `p > a`

```
       p > a {
         color: black;
         text-decoration: none;
       }
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/FedeMITIC/pen/GyXQax

CSS reference about selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: If the color of the parent is changed, the child won't follow.

Comment: Yes, it's true. In that case, your answer is the most correct. I didn't think about that eventuality, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

a {  text-decoration: none !important;   color: #000;}

Answer (score 1):

This will remove your colour as well as the underline that anchor tag exists with

```
a 
{
  text-decoration: none ;
}
a:hover
{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```