# Underscore appears at end of images anchors

Tags: html

There is a problem with my code where tiny underscores appear on the bottom-right corner of my anchor image. I have no idea how to fix it. I've heard answerers form other similar questions saying you have to add a closing `</a>` tag at the end, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, as I already have those tags included in my code. I also don't remember adding underscores into my code on purpose, so I have no idea how it can be removed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background-image: url(https://img.michaels.com/L6/3/IOGLO/852866719/201341423/10151236.jpg?fit=inside|1024:1024);">
<button onclick="executeCommand()" style="border: 0; background: 0;"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/54/54527.svg" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></button><div id="search"></div>
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.ca/" target="_blank"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/Chrome__logo.max-2800x2800.png" alt="Google Chrome" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 0px 0px 5px 4px">
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://mail.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/Gmail_logo.max-2800x2800.png" alt="Google Mail" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 4px">
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/G/google-docs-logo-6A8CD4F30A-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Google Docs" style="width: 30px; height: 40px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 9px">
</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Ned_Tu_ge6GgJZ_lIO_5mieIEmjDpq9kfgD05wapmvzcInvT4qQMxhxq_hEazf8ZsqA=w300" alt="Youtube" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 5px 0px 5px 4px">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the w3schools tryit editor. Is that the problem?

Comment: Put the `</a>` tag directly after the `<img>` tag, i.e. get rid of the newline (which will be parsed as a space).

Comment: And make sure your example is a [mcve]!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the underline for anchors(links)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks)

Comment: @dash2 thanks that answer worked. q

Comment: Interestingly, adding `<br>` after the last `<a>` statement adds an underscore there as well. Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS line

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I feel more comfortable using `<a style='    '>` instead.

Comment: Yeah you can do it.

Comment: You need to add style to every anchor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this person, is the answer:
"Put the “a” tag directly after the “img” tag, i.e. get rid of the newline (which will be parsed as a space). – user3603486 Apr 1 '18 at 15:13"

see my example att: anchor underscores: [image]