# Click event's problems in the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I want that my menu has the ability that when I click on other part of my website, my menu closes (not open).

I know I have to use a click event for that, but when I used a click event, my menu had 2 unwanted problems:

1- first of all when clicked on the list of menu it shows the underline for every item of menu that is unwanted.

2 - after clicking on other part of my website , my menu totally be disappeared and it (menu) dosen't show in my website , that is too bad.

Then I wanna using click events (or every tthing like that) but how can I solve these unwanted problems ?

I am too confused , I Appreciate it if you get the code instead of the link,thanks.

### The code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.closest('.nav')) {
    return;
  } else {
   document.querySelector('#dropdown').style.display = 'none';  
  }
});
  
 function toggle(element) {
  const nodes = getChildNodes(element.parentElement);
  if(nodes[1].style.display === 'block') {
    nodes[1].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    nodes[1].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function getChildNodes(node) {
  let children = new Array();
  for(const child in node.childNodes) {
    if(node.childNodes[child].nodeType == 1) {
      children.push(node.childNodes[child]);
    }
  }
  return children;
}
```

```css
#ABT-Container  {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  width:100%; float:right;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 6px 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: white; /* for non-css3 browsers */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.nav .current a, .nav li:hover > a {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: white; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: #444;
    border-top: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);*/
}
/* sub levels link hover */
.nav ul li:hover a, .nav li:hover li a {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
.nav ul a:hover {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #ff4718 !important; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff4718', endColorstr='#FF0000'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#ff4718), to(#FF0000)) !important; /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff4718,  #FF0000) !important; /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}


.nav li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

/* main level link */
.nav a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #353535;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding:  8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0em;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

/* level 2 list */
.nav ul {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF; /* for non-css3 browsers */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* dropdown */
.nav ul li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

/* level 3+ list */
.nav ul ul {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  right: 181px;
  top: -3px;
}

/* rounded corners for first and last child */
.nav ul li:first-child > a {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 1px;
}

.nav ul li:last-child > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1px;
}

/* clearfix */
.nav:after {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

* html .nav {
  height: 1%;
}

.menu_line{
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.expand{font-size:24px;float: left;margin: 0px -5px;}

.menu_line{
 width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
 color: black;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="bg1" class="navbar">
                
                  
      
                    <div id="ABT-Container">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/new pic/Home.png" width="166" height="40"/></a>
    
    
    
    
<ul class="nav" id="dropdown"><li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><p class="menu_line"></p><p class="menu_line"></p><p class="menu_line"></p></a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Our Technology</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Sub-Row</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
</a></li></ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Sub-Row</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 2 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row clicked')">Sub-Row</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row clicked')">Sub-Row</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Multi-Levels</a>
<ul id="dropdoswn">
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Team clicked')">Team</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 11 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 11</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 22 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 22</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 33 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 33</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
                   
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Sales clicked')">Sales</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Another Link clicked')">Another Link</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Department</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li><li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Services</a></li>   
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">About US</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Our Links</a></li>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
                    <!-- Header Nav End -->
                    
            </nav>
```

Comment: To remove the underline part of your anchor tags, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.closest('.nav')) {
    return;
  } else {
   document.querySelector('#subMenu').style.display = 'none';
   // I added an ID to the inner unordered list
  }
});
  
 function toggle(element) {
  const nodes = getChildNodes(element.parentElement);
  if(nodes[1].style.display === 'block') {
    nodes[1].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    nodes[1].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function getChildNodes(node) {
  let children = new Array();
  for(const child in node.childNodes) {
    if(node.childNodes[child].nodeType == 1) {
      children.push(node.childNodes[child]);
    }
  }
  return children;
}
```

```css
#ABT-Container  {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  width:100%; float:right;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 6px 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: white; /* for non-css3 browsers */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.nav .current a, .nav li:hover > a {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: white; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: #444;
    border-top: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);*/
}
/* sub levels link hover */
.nav ul li:hover a, .nav li:hover li a {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
.nav ul a:hover {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #ff4718 !important; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff4718', endColorstr='#FF0000'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#ff4718), to(#FF0000)) !important; /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff4718,  #FF0000) !important; /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}


.nav li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

/* main level link */
.nav a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #353535;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding:  8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0em;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

/* level 2 list */
.nav ul {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF; /* for non-css3 browsers */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#FFFFFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #FFFFFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* dropdown */
.nav ul li {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav ul a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

/* level 3+ list */
.nav ul ul {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  right: 181px;
  top: -3px;
}

/* rounded corners for first and last child */
.nav ul li:first-child > a {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 1px;
}

.nav ul li:last-child > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1px;
}

/* clearfix */
.nav:after {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

* html .nav {
  height: 1%;
}

.menu_line{
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.expand{font-size:24px;float: left;margin: 0px -5px;}

.menu_line{
 width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
 color: black;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="bg1" class="navbar">
                
                  
      
                    <div id="ABT-Container">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/new pic/Home.png" width="166" height="40"/></a>
    
    
    
    
<ul class="nav" id="dropdown"><li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><p class="menu_line"></p><p class="menu_line"></p><p class="menu_line"></p></a>
 <ul id="subMenu">
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Our Technology</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Sub-Row</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 1 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 1</a></li>
</a></li></ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Sub-Row</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row 2 clicked')">Sub Sub-Row 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row clicked')">Sub-Row</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub Sub-Row clicked')">Sub-Row</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Multi-Levels</a>
<ul id="dropdoswn">
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Team clicked')">Team</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 11 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 11</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 22 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 22</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 33 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 33</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
                   
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 1 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Sales clicked')">Sales</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Another Link clicked')">Another Link</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)"><span class="expand">&#x25C2;</span>Department</a>
 <ul>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#" onclick="console.log('Sub-Level Item 2 clicked')">Sub-Level Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li><li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Services</a></li>   
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">About US</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
<li class="w3-animate-right"><a href="#">Our Links</a></li>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
                    <!-- Header Nav End -->
                    
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is making all your `div` element that have `id="dropdown"` (parent and childrens) disappear, because you is setting to `display: none`

Try remove it
`document.querySelector('#dropdown').style.display = 'none';`

instead try to call the `toggle() funciton`