# how can I remove underline text in my code?

Tags: html, css

[image]

how can I remove underline text in my code ?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041388/how-to-remove-the-underline-for-anchorslinks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text-decoration : none ;` tag in your CSS file or `style` code .

Answer (score 1):

Give your tag, css property:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your css

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try implementing this in your css file or `<style>` tag

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```