# Adapting CSS & HTML for sprite hover over

Tags: html, css

I want my image to change when I hover over it using sprites.

This is my current CSS:

```
.main_advert {
    width:754px;
    margin:20px auto 0px auto;
    padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.main_advert img, .advert img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #333;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #028EC9;
}
```

Current HTML:

```
  <div class="main_advert">
      <a href="http://website.com" target="_blank"><img alt="Website" src="./images/website.jpg" border="0" /></a>
```

I've learned the following does what I want, except it is not compatible with my current CSS.

Incompatible CSS:

```
.main_advert {
    background: url(./images/website.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.main_advert:hover {
    background-position: 0 -90px;
}
```

**So how would I go about adapting the above CSS into my current?**

Comment: the second hover overwrite the first one

Comment: @Zoltan Toth apologies... that was the older version I tried. Removing the un-needed css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's my take on things](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/1/).

[View the source for comments](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/1/edit).

---

(Posting *jsbin* code here for completeness' sake.)

**Based on the assumption that you can't modify HTML, here's a couple of solutions:**

---

## EXAMPLE 1

**Not using a sprite.**

#### CSS:

```
.main_advert_1 {
    width: 64px; /* Width of logo. */
    height: 64px; /* Height of logo. */
    background: url(http://drfatmaclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/before-after_juvederm1-64x64.jpg) no-repeat;
}
    .main_advert_1 a {
        /* Now the <a> fills the parent container: */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block; /* Required for <a> to expand to fill parent. */
    }
        .main_advert_1 img { display: block; }
            .main_advert_1 a:hover img { display: none; } /* Hide on hover. */
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="main_advert_1">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Website" src="http://drfatmaclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/before_after_restylane1-64x64.jpg">
    </a>
</div> <!-- /.main_advert_1 -->
```

---

## EXAMPLE 2:

**Using a sprite.**

#### CSS:

```
.main_advert_2 {
    /* Width and height of logo/ad/whatever. */
    width: 284px;
    height: 284px;
}
    .main_advert_2 img { display: none; } /* Just hide it so you can do stuff with the <a> only. */
    .main_advert_2 a {
        /* Random sprite found on web: */
        background-image: url(https://dw1.s81c.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/waldensponderings/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/sel-tux_wizard.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* IBID: */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block; /* IBID */
    }
        .main_advert_2 a:hover { background-position: 0 -284px; } /* Position sprite on :hover. */
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="main_advert_2">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Website" src="http://drfatmaclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/before_after_restylane1-64x64.jpg">
    </a>
</div> <!-- /.main_advert_2 -->
```

---

If you could edit the HTML, then you could remove the `<img>` and your code would be a tad "cleaner".

Is that of any help?

---

## EDIT #1

[Here's a new version](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/2) based on your comments.

#### CSS:

```
.main_advert {
    /* Width and height of logo/ad/whatever. */
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
}
    .main_advert img { display: none; } /* Just hide it so you can do stuff with the <a> only. */
    .main_advert a {
        /* Random sprite found on web: */
        background-image: url(http://trickerygaming.net/tsf2/images/registeroof.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* IBID: */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block; /* IBID */
    }
        .main_advert a:hover { background-position: 0 -90px; } /* Position sprite on :hover. */
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="main_advert">

    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img border="0" src="./images/register.jpg" alt="Register"></a>

</div>
```

Better?

---

## EDIT #2

[Here's a version where I removed the `<img>` and replaced it with text.](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/4/)

([View the HTML/CSS here](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/4/edit).)

#### CSS:

```
.main_advert {
    text-indent: -999em; /* This hides the "Register on our forums." text (see below). */
    /* Width and height of logo/ad/whatever: */
    width: 728px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centers this container inside parent. */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hides indented text from above. */ 
}
    .main_advert a {
        /* Your image: */
        background-image: url(http://trickerygaming.net/tsf2/images/registeroof.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* IBID: */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block; /* Allows <a> to fill parent. */
    }
        .main_advert a:hover { background-position: 0 -90px; } /* Position sprite on :hover. */
        .main_advert a:active,
        .main_advert a:focus { outline: none; } /* Removes ugly outline, on click, in some browsers. */
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="main_advert">

    <a target="_blank" href="#">Register on our forums.</a>

</div> <!-- /.main_advert -->
```

For a "sprite" technique, I like this approach the best.

---

Actually, if it were me, I'd probably try doing things with CSS3.

For CSS3 tools to give you ideas/inspiration, check out:

- http://css3generator.com/
- http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: This is what I get when I try your method: http://trickerygaming.net/tsf2/sprites.html What it should be (except with a sprite in the register now position) http://trickerygaming.net/tsf2/index.html Now the sprite I am trying to use: http://trickerygaming.net/tsf2/images/registeroof.png

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question? What would I need to edit the HTML to? I am sorry for my incompetence. I am a beginner in HTML etc

Comment: I've updated my answer. See the "EDIT" section. I'm asking if you can edit the HTML because you're asking to do a "sprite" technique, but you are putting an image into the page (ussually, when you do a sprite technique, you don't have an <img> tag occupying the same location... I'm just wondering if you can remove the <img>? If you can remove the <img> then we could add some text that says "Register on our forums" which would make it more SEO friendly (at a minimum).

Comment: Check **EDIT #2** for an example of you code without the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Quick comment: I just updated my code... I missed a close `*/` for a CSS comment. The updated code [is here](http://jsbin.com/abuwim/4/edit). G'night! :)

Comment: This solved everything except the border around the image as shown on the index.html page. Anyways, THANKS SO MUCH! It's working.

Comment: @Skyle777 Sure thing. Check out [this post for info on borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images). Without looking myself, you probably just need: `.main_advert img { border: 0; }`, but check out my **EDIT #2** for an example that doesn't use an `<img>`. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Use [that tool](http://csssprites.com/) to generate your sprite and css

Comment: I already have a sprite image created. This also will not help me integrate into my current CSS either. The last CSS in my post works on a blank page with nothing else but not on my current website where I want it.

Comment: what is happening when you hover it?

Comment: The incompatible CSS I provided is NOT on my live site. I don't know how I would I adapt it to my current CSS which is at the top of my post.