# Remove default browser styling of active state of link?

Tags: css

Ive styled the :active state of a link already but when you click it in Chrome you get a blue outline as you can see in the 2nd button below:

[image]

How can I disable this styling, ideally for all browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the outline around hyperlinks images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a { border: 0 }

You should edit the anchor tag's global CSS, not just for its active state. Also, look into modernizr.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `outline: 0;` to the CSS does the trick for form elements and buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the CSS property `outline`.

**For Example**

```
a {
  outline: none;
}
```