# Is there a way to link to a css box without the blue link dot?

Tags: html, css

Ok so it's probably not the best coding practices but I used an image sliced up and assigned them a z layer 1; and then I created transparent boxes on z layer 2. Everything was going wonderful until I tried to assign a link with no text. There is a blue dot inside the image from the `<a href="">` tag... What I would like to do is make it completely invisible as if I'm clicking on the image and it takes me to another page... I know there are other ways to do it, but is there some simple css I can add to get rid of the blue link dot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the outline around hyperlinks images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images)

Comment: what is css box..? Before telling what you have tried to DO? tell what you were trying to do?

Comment: Ok so to clarify I have this CSS #indexPhoneCall {
 position:absolute;
 top: 145px;
 left: 740px;
 border:0px;
 z-index:2;
 height:175px;
 width:320px;
 }

Comment: And what I am trying to do is get rid of the blue link dot that appears over the image I placed the borderless box. Although there is an empty box, there is still a blue dot in the top left of the box. I think of it as if someone drew a picture. Then I wanted to take a clear plastic sheet and put it over it that is clickable since the artwork itself is not. Does that make sense?