# How do I remove outline on link click?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, outline

When I click a link on my website it is creating an outline around the link like so

[image]

I've tried adding:

```
a.image-link:focus { outline: 0; }
```

and

```
a {outline : none;}
```

But nothing seems to get rid of it. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: maybe `a:active{outline: 0;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the outline around hyperlinks images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images)

Comment: Be aware that those outlines are very important for some disabled users. Many of us have consented to their existence for that reason. https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/28/stop-messing-with-the-browsers-default-focus-outline/

Answer (score 89):

You can just use this:

```
a:active, a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I´ve updated the solutions for you problem. I´ve aded the focus state on link and added also the moz-outline property. :) Can you please confirm?

Comment: `border` has nothing todo with it.

Comment: outline: 0;
was very useful to know

Answer (score 12):

If at-least one of the solutions above doesn't work for anyone. Give this a try as well

```
a:active, a:focus {
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add `a:visited { outline: none; }` in your style file.

Answer (score 4):

try all of these until u find what works in your case.

```
a:active, a:focus, li:focus, li:active {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;        
    text-decoration: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Found out in my CSS that there was code already being generated to create an outline on `a:active`. This was overriding my code and removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

> I battled this for a while and this worked for me on WordPress 5.5.3 with StoreFront theme:

```
a:hover,
a:active {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me**

```
a:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
a, a:active, a:focus {outline: none;}

```html
a, a:active, a:focus {outline: none;}
```