# When i click my image on outlook it shows like a edit border

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I'm working on an emailing and my client works with outlook 2013. When they click on an image that has a link, it creates a border that looks like an editing border. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: have you tried outline:0 on focus ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635588/how-do-i-remove-outline-on-link-click , `a:focus { outline:0}`

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Are you using vml? If yes then that is the functionality of Outlook and can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try all these options, one of them should work:

1. Set a border as an attribute of the element like `<img src="..." alt="..." border="0">`
2. On CSS set `a img { border: none; }`
3. on CSS set `a {outline : none;}`
4. on CSS set `a img {outline : none;}`