# Font-Awesome icon with an onclick event set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use the following font-awesome icon

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
```

as a delete icon next to items in a list on my page like this:

```
Item 1  delete-icon
Item 2  delete-icon
```

On click of one of these icons I need to run a JavaScript function...

What html element should I be wrapping the icon with? I noticed that when I use an anchor tag it turns blue and when I use a button it ends up being wrapped in a button. Are there any other options?

Essentially I want to do this

```
<a onclick="Remove()"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
```

or this

```
<button onclick="Remove()"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
```

But have only the icon appear as is with no modifications. No blue color, and not wrapped inside a button.

Comment: try This....
<a href='javascript:myFunction();'>Text <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>

Comment: Sorry this still highlights it in blue because it is considered an anchor tag. I know I could easily create a css style to make it black again, but was seeing if there was a better way.

Comment: How to add a click event, if the font awesome icons are used in the pseudoelement like:   &::before{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content : "\f0d9";
  display: inline-block;
     padding-right: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
 }

Answer (score 50):

Simply use a `div` tag or `span` tag with `onclick`

```
<div onclick="myFunction()">
       <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
</div>
```

or

```
<span onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in every situation... Edit: which might be why no answer was accepted at all.

Comment: I dont think this is the proper way. Especially since HTML5, semantics matter. Also, for screen readers and accessibility, a button would probably be better. Not saying I have a better idea than removing default styles from the <button> element, but to me, your solution (that is currently being used *everywhere*) does not look good

Answer (score 16):

Either remove the blue outline from the anchor tag [with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images) or set the `onclick`-handler on the font awesome icon itself:

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" onclick="Remove()"></i>
```

Comment: This works if the fontawesome icons are being rendered with web fonts and css, but not if they are rendered with svg/js.  For example, in my app which uses vuetify with fontawesome icons, the icons are rendered using svg; and then this technique stops working :\

Answer (score 2):

Here a way to use font awesome with bootstrap.

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary logout" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true">Logout</i>
    </a>
{{else}}
    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary login-toggle">Register/Login</a>
{{/if}}
```

Corresponding JS to make a click event on **LOGOUT** button

```
'click .logout':() =>{
//your JS functionality.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="color: inherit;" onclick="Remove()"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
```

This will take the default color of the icon.
You can also specify any color, you wish.