# Html CSS search bar: nothing happens when clicking the icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using a website template which has a search form with an icon in the text field.
[image: Search icon]

When a value is entered and the user clicks on 'Enter' the form is executed. However, when the search icon is clicked, nothing happens.

[image: Nothing happens when clicking the icon]

The icon is created via the awesome font library http://fontawesome.io/
and added via css

```
content: '\f002';
```

Here is a fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/BamBamm/df2gzkbb/10/

How can I fix this? Thank you.

```css
#search form {
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
}

#search form:before {
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-transform: none !important;
}

#search form:before {
 -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
 -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
 transform: scaleX(-1);
 color: #7f888f;
 content: '\f002';
 cursor: default;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 height: 2em;
 line-height: 2em;
 opacity: 0.325;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 width: 2em;
}
    
input[type="text"] {
    height: 2.75em;
}

input[type="text"] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0.375em;
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}

body, input, select, textarea {
    color: #7f888f;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.65;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="search" class="alt">
 <form action="javascript:alert('Inner Function performed!');">
   <input type="text" name="search_query" value="defaultValue"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would anything happen when you click on the icon? Only expected functionality is to focus the search field. Just because it is a magnifying glass, the browser does not magically know it has to search when it is clicked. You can make a button outside the search field and have that submit the form.

Comment: There is no code to be executed when click the icon, you will need some javascript... Enter is working because it's the normal behavior to a form.

Comment: if you use `font-awesome` as it's documented on their website (in an HTML tag not CSS), then you could add an `onclick` to the tag easily.

Comment: @CalvinNunes You cannot attach an event handler to a pseudo element because it is not in the DOM.

Comment: @connexo, I know that, but if he wants to have a click event, he'll need to create an element to put this icon inside, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185974/font-awesome-icon-with-an-onclick-event-set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give icon on submit button

Please Check that code :

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="javascript:alert('Inner Function performed!');">
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, adding a full-blown CSS library for your solution only because you don't seem to know how to add fontawesome icons otherwise. That's like buying a library of books when all you need is a word.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the icon on a pseudo element in the form, you can add a submit button that has the same icon:

https://jsfiddle.net/df2gzkbb/12/

Even though this works, I would recommend you do not change the behaviour at all. Sending the form via clicking of the icon in my opinion would be unexpected behaviour and thus, worsen the user experience.

```css
#search form {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

#search form button {
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
}

#search form button:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  color: #7f888f;
  content: '\f002';
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  opacity: 0.325;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 2.75em;
}

input[type="text"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.375em;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

body,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: #7f888f;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.65;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css " />
<div id="search" class="alt">
  <form action="javascript:alert('Inner Function performed!');">
    <input type="text" name="search_query" value="defaultValue" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a span to the DOM and add an event to it :

```js
$('#glyphicon').click(function(){
  $('#myform').submit()
})
```

```css
#glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    left: -25px;
    top: 6px;
    background-image: url(http://wfarm4.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set110/37275f5a.png);
    background-size : 100% 100%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search" class="alt">
 <form id="myform" action="javascript:alert('Inner Function performed!');">
   <input type="text" name="search_query" value="defaultValue"/>
    <span id="glyphicon">
  
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use a `span` + jQuery when a simple `<button type="submit"></button>` does the job?

Comment: I dont love the submit button, I always love to control over what happen when I click on something, perhaps I want to do something else before or submiting ( maybe on the future? ) to the server.

Comment: Then simply attach an event handler to the submit button. No single valid reason for a span over a button from your side so far.

Comment: If you want my personal opinion , I try to avoid submit button and form tag as well, and as I said I try to do everything by myself. It is my personal opinion, I like to do everything by my self, no need to let a button do the job that i am supposed to do.

Comment: Actually the opposite is the case. No need to do it yourself when there is a semantically appropriate element that does exactly what is expected. You really need to take a deep dive into semantics, and why that matters **alot**.

Answer (score 1):

Set an event for the onclick of the search button.
The code should be something like this

```
<div onclick="myFunction()">
       <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
</div>
```

The form takes in the **Enter** key stroke as a submit. You have to set an event for mouse click events.

Comment: Why use a `div` + onclick when a simple `<button type="submit"></button>` does the job?

Comment: Also a click would make a focussing click a submit

Comment: I won't vote down because it's not wrong, it works, but it's not the best way to solve...