# H1 link boarder in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem. On https://analytium.co.uk/our-cases/ when i click on header see border. It problem only in chrome.  Does anyone have any idea why this border appears when clicking?  [image]

Comment: It's a outline not border.

Comment: And only one actually good answer in that duplicate, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/815827/1427878 (The others are the same usability and accessibility killing _crap_ as in the answers here as well so far …)

Answer (score -1):

```
.myLinkHeading {
  outline : none;
}
```

Just remove the anchor outline.

Answer (score -1):

You have default css coming from bootstrap

```
a:focus {
outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

you should replace by

```
.works-name a{
outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add on you inline css:

```
<a href="https://analytium.co.uk/cases/sas-and-fraud-prevention-brief-overview/" style="color: #444;outline:none" tabindex="0">
```

SAS® and Fraud Prevention (Brief Overview)

or add on your css file :

```
a, a:focus {
outline:none;
}
```