# HTML/CCS: how to remove the box around link element?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CCS. I would like to have an invisible link but I don't want to set the style of 'a' tags directly, instead I would like to set the style of its parent element so that it becomes invisible.

This is what I tried:

```css
div {
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  border: inherit;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div><a href='/trap'> inherit </a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

It doesn't show the text inside the 'a' tag, but it still shows a box around it, how I can get rid of that box?

Comment: I have not understood what you are trying to achieve but in fact the anchor is shown properly, just the color of its text ('inherit') is white and it seems like it's not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the outline around hyperlinks images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814366/how-can-i-remove-the-outline-around-hyperlinks-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the outline box.
You can remove it with:

```css
div{
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

a, a:focus{
  color: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  outline:none;
} 
a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div><a href='/trap'> inherit </a></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this CSS property to hide the `outline` in all your link elements :

```
a, a:focus {outline : none;}
```

In the  other hand, if you want to make an element invisible, but still be able  to receive click interactions on it, you can play with the `opacity` CSS property (setting the font color to white is not an elegant solution)

```
a{ opacity:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'box' around your link has a default `outline` property defined. Be sure to include `outline: none;` to any element or pseudo-selector that includes this treatment.

```css
div {
  color: #ccc; /* for testing purposes*/
  border: none;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  border: inherit;
}

a:link {
  outline: none; /* removes outline */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div><a href='#trap'> inherit </a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused why you are trying to make a link that is invisible in the first place, but the box you are referring to is most likely the focus box. Typically used to make it easy for the user to know what they are selecting and is good for accessibility-- it's usually not recommended to remove.

You can though by adding the code below.

```
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```